# Por que o método main deve despachar a criação da GUI para a EDT em uma aplicação swing?

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

Conforme a especificação do Java, grande parte da API do Swing não é *Thread-Safe* e deve rodar na [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Como, após inicializar o GUI os eventos são disparados de dentro [da própria EDT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3541425/664577), a não ser que você esteja usando *threads* em background que precisam atualizar a UI, isso não costuma ser um problema.

Porém, como o método `main` roda em sua própria *thread* (inicial), é comum o uso de `invokeLater` para despachar a exibição da GUI para a EDT:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            exibirTela();
        }
    });
}
```

Veja que, após exibir a tela, o método `main` não executa mais nada. Na teoria, nenhum código concorrente à EDT parece ser executado na *thread* principal.

Minha dúvida é: Existe um motivo para termos que despachar a criação da tela para a EDT?

Na stack overflow em inglês encontrei [uma referência](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15302285/664577) que aponta para a documentação dizendo que a *thread* inicial não deve criar o GUI pois "quase todo o código que cria ou interage com componentes Swing deve rodar na EDT". Esse dias porém vi o código de uma aplicação que está rodando a quase 10 anos em produção. Esse código cria e exibe a `JFrame` principal diretamente do `main`; nunca houve nenhum problema reportado sobre o funcionamento dessa aplicação.

Nesse sentido, quais seriam os problemas de concorrência possíveis? Se não usarmos `invokeLater` o que ficará rodando na *thread* principal e o que ficará rodando na EDT (e.g.: A `JFrame` principal fica na *thread* principal, mas seus eventos vão para a EDT)?

Comment: Há alguns anos eu programava em Swing e eu tinha o costume de iniciar a interface Swing diretamente na Classe Principal e até mesmo ela ser uma extenção do `JFrame`, eu nunca tive problema, porém minha memória me alerta sobre momentos que eu tive travamento de alguns processos desde que ambos fossem executados na mesma thread que deu inicio ao JFrame..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

O AWT precisa de uma thread dedicada porque ele deve receber eventos de teclado, mouse e *repaint* de tela de forma contínua e rápida, em loop (e o Swing executa em cima do AWT). Desta forma, o AWT não poderia ser executado em alguma thread de usuário arbitrária porque ele deve necessariamente tomar o controle exclusivo da thread.

Além disso, o AWT/Swing **não é** *thread-safe*. Tornar o Swing *thread-safe* consistiria em um enorme esforço de programação por um ganho no mínimo questionável.

Desta forma, a conclusão é o AWT/Swing tem que rodar em uma thread única para ele e que nenhuma outra thread poderá acessá-lo diretamente. Daí é que temos a EDT (*Event-Dispatch Thread*).

Embora em teoria é possível em alguns casos manipular componentes Swing fora da EDT sem ter problemas de concorrência, esta é uma tarefa bastante difícil, perigosa e frágil, pois não é claro quais são os casos em que é seguro fazer-se isso, e mesmo que alguns possam ser encontrados, eles podem ser invalidados por outras coisas que estejam manipulando o Swing, que por sua vez também podem ser invalidados por outras coisas. Assim podemos em geral assumir que **nunca é seguro manipular um componente Swing fora da EDT**.

Por outro lado, ao adotar-se a regra de que componentes Swing devem ser manipulados apenas na EDT, todos os problemas de *thread-safety* referentes a isso desaparecem.

Pode-se argumentar que um componente Swing poderia ser manipulado fora da EDT antes dele ser de fato publicado ao Swing. Inclusive, isso era o que a Sun dizia antigamente (até o J2SE 1.4):

> Once a Swing component has been realized, all code that might affect or depend on the state of that component should be executed in the event-dispatching thread.

Que traduzindo para o português é:

> Uma vez que um componente Swing foi *realizado*, todo o código que pode afetar ou depender do estado deste componente deverá ser executado na *event-dispatching thread*.

Entende-se como "realizar" algo como publicar o componente para o Swing começar a manipulá-lo.

**ESQUEÇA ISTO HOJE EM DIA**. O motivo é que o código que manipula um componente Swing pode acabar por realizá-lo, e assim é muito difícil saber quando um componente Swing foi realizado ou não. Uma chamada a algo como `component.setVisible(true)` ou `jframe.pack()` geralmente implicam na realização, mas outras chamadas mais simples, até mesmo getters também podem acabar por fazê-lo. A partir do Java 5 a recomendação é que qualquer manipulação de um componente Swing deve obrigatoriamente ser feita dentro da EDT.

Por fim, ao criar e manipular componentes Swing dentro da thread principal do programa (a que executa o método `main`), a regra de manipulá-los dentro da EDT é violada. A solução para isso é usar o `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)` ou o equivalente `EventQueue.invokeLater(Runnable)`. Dependendo do caso pode-se usar `invokeAndWait` em lugar de `invokeLater` caso alguma operação deva ser executada apenas após o término da interação com o Swing. O método `EventQueue.isDispatchThread()` pode ser usado para que um código saiba se a thread no qual ele está rodando é a EDT ou não.

Veja mais detalhes aqui: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077754/core-java/swing-threading-and-the-event-dispatch-thread.html?page=5

Answer (score 13):

O que acontece é que todo evento Swing vai ser enviado na EDT. Portanto fazendo no EDT, enquanto o se `exibirTela` está rodando nenhum outro evento Swing será despachado ou tratado. Nenhum click ou movimento de mouse.

Agora se você cria no `main` e a criação demora você pode ter eventos Swing sendo tratado enquanto seu código de inicialização está mudando coisas. Para uma tela pequena isso pode não ser um problema, mas se você faz algo demorado parte da sua tela pode não estar pronta quando o usuário começa a mandar eventos.

A ideia de colocar toda ação Swing no EDT é evitar concorrência na atualização de componentes. Em linha gerais qualquer operação que demore mais de 100ms será perceptível pelo usuário. Lembre-se também que operações como `paint` podem demorar um pouco.

Eu já tive programas que produzem null pointer e outras exceções por questão de executar as coisas fora do EDT. Nada fatal mais indicativo que algo não está bem no código.