# Usar o Napkin LookAndFeel

Tags: java, swing, gui

Estou usando o Eclipse IDE e tenho esse código:

```
package br.com.caelum.argentum.ui;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class ArgentumUI {

    private JFrame janela;
    private JPanel painelPrincipal;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {  
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("napkin.NapkinLookAndFeel");  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
               e.printStackTrace();  
        }
        new ArgentumUI().montaTela();
    }

    public void montaTela() {
        preparaJanela();
        preparaPainelPrincipal();
        preparaBotaoCarregar();
        preparaBotaoSair();
        mostraJanela();
    }


    private void mostraJanela() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        janela.pack();
        janela.setSize(540, 540);
        janela.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void preparaBotaoSair() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JButton botaoSair = new JButton("Sair");
        botaoSair.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        botaoSair.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        painelPrincipal.add(botaoSair);
    }

    private void preparaBotaoCarregar() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JButton botaoCarregar = new JButton("Carregar XML");
        botaoCarregar.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        botaoCarregar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new EscolhedorDeXML().escolhe();
            }
        });
        painelPrincipal.add(botaoCarregar);

    }

    private void preparaPainelPrincipal() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        painelPrincipal = new JPanel();
        janela.add(painelPrincipal);
    }

    private void preparaJanela() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        janela = new JFrame("Argentum");
        janela.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

O Napkin já está nas Referenced Libraries, porém estou recebendo esses erros:

```
keys we didn't overwrite: []
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is decorated
    at java.awt.Frame.setBackground(Frame.java:986)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.frameInit(JFrame.java:253)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:219)
    at br.com.caelum.argentum.ui.ArgentumUI.preparaJanela(ArgentumUI.java:77)
    at br.com.caelum.argentum.ui.ArgentumUI.montaTela(ArgentumUI.java:26)
    at br.com.caelum.argentum.ui.ArgentumUI.main(ArgentumUI.java:22)
```

Como corrigir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Victor, aqui está (eita código difícil de rodar).

[image: Aplicativo rodando no Windows 7]

[image: Aplicativo rodando no openSUSE 13.1 / KDE Plasma]

Aparentemente houve uma quebra de compatibilidade entre o JDK 6 e o JDK 7 no que se refere a janelas translucidas (veja [esse post no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259269/is-the-java-tutorials-translucent-window-example-giving-trouble-to-those-playing)). O NapKin dependente dessa *feature* (veja [*Error in NapKin Look and Feel* no CodeRanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/566070/GUI/java/Error-NapKin-Feel)).

O *[workaround](http://www.coderanch.com/t/566070/GUI/java/Error-NapKin-Feel#2571514)* sugerido por [Rob Spoor](http://www.coderanch.com/u/110217/Rob-Spoor) é:

- Não configure o *look & feel* logo de cara.
- Crie sua interface com o usuário.
- Chame `setUndecorated(true)` na *frame*.
- Configure o *look & feel*.
- Chame `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI` para a *frame*.
- Se necessário, chame `setUndecorated(false)` na *frame*.

No seu caso não foi necessário chamar `setUndecorated`.

Fiz as seguintes alterações:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                ArgentumUI ui = new ArgentumUI();
                ui.montaTela();
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel("napkin.NapkinLookAndFeel");
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(ui.janela);
                ui.mostraJanela();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ArgentumUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

E atualizei o método `montaJanela` para não mostrar a janela imediatamente após a construção:

```
public void montaTela() {
    preparaJanela();
    preparaPainelPrincipal();
    preparaBotaoCarregar();
    preparaBotaoSair();
    //mostraJanela();
}
```

E tudo funcionou como deveria.

---

A questão do `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` não é estritamente necessária para fazer o código rodar (veja [Aplicação Swing. Por que o método main deve despachar a criação da GUI para a EDT?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2017/100)), porém, é melhor prevenir do que remediar. O tutorial da Oracle [deixa claro](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) que quase todo código que cria ou interage com componentes Swing deve rodar na [EDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Anthony, porém surgiu outro problema agora ... Ao clicar em carregar XML a linha new EscolhedorDeXML.escolhe(); é executada, e ela gera uma caixa de diálogo sem nada... Sem querer abusar da sua boa vontade, mas poderia me dar mais uma ajuda? Vou deixar o link para o Gist com o código dessa classe. Obrigado https://gist.github.com/VictorGee/430474575c68c04d3212

Comment: Oi Victor, é o mesmo problema só que dentro de uma `JDialog` criada pelo `JFileChooser`, não vejo nenhuma maneira simples de fazer isso rodar. Você pode tentar abrir outra pergunta, porém eu acho que você deve tentar rodar o aplicativo com outro Look And Feel.

Comment: Ok, Anthony, obrigado !