# JLabel não é exibido

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

Criei uma label onde nela conteria o status do processo de conexão com o banco de dados, mas ela não aparece e eu não tenho a mínima ideia do porquê isso acontece, já se fazem três dias que eu olho pro código e não sei o que acontece, seria ótimo se alguém me ajudasse a achar a causa disso, por favor.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Funcionarios extends Janela implements ActionListener{

    Connection conexao = Conectar.getConnection();
    String status = Conectar.status;

    JTextField txt_codigo, txt_nome, txt_ende, txt_tele, txt_nasc, txt_cpf, txt_carg, txt_email;
    JLabel lbl_codigo, lbl_nome, lbl_ende, lbl_tele, lbl_nasc, lbl_cpf, lbl_carg, lbl_email, lbl_status, txt_status;
    JButton btn_inserir, btn_alterar, btn_excluir, btn_consultar;

    public Funcionarios(){
        super("Funcionários", new Dimension(460, 400));
        //getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(56, 76, 244));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(null);

        // Definição do posicionamento das labels
        lbl_codigo = new JLabel("Código:");
        lbl_codigo.setBounds(10, 30, 80, 15);
        getContentPane().add(lbl_codigo);
        lbl_codigo.setForeground(Color.black);

        lbl_nome = new JLabel("Nome:");
        lbl_nome.setBounds(10, 60, 80, 15);
        getContentPane().add(lbl_nome);
        lbl_nome.setForeground(Color.black);

        lbl_ende = new JLabel("Endereço:");
        lbl_ende.setBounds(10, 90, 80, 15);
        getContentPane().add(lbl_ende);
        lbl_ende.setForeground(Color.black);

        lbl_tele = new JLabel("Telefone:");
        lbl_tele.setBounds(10, 120, 60, 15);
        getContentPane().add(lbl_tele);
        lbl_tele.setForeground(Color.black);

        lbl_nasc = new JLabel("Data de nascimento:");
        lbl_nasc.setBounds(10, 150, 200, 15);
        getContentPane().add(lbl_nasc);
        lbl_nasc.setForeground(Color.black);

        lbl_cpf = new JLabel("CPF:");
        lbl_cpf.setBounds(10, 180, 50, 15);
        getContentPane().add(lbl_cpf);
        lbl_cpf.setForeground(Color.black);

        lbl_carg = new JLabel("Cargo:");
        lbl_carg.setBounds(10, 210, 50, 15);
        getContentPane().add(lbl_carg);
        lbl_carg.setForeground(Color.black);

        lbl_email = new JLabel("E-mail:");
        lbl_email.setBounds(10, 240, 50, 15);
        getContentPane().add(lbl_email);
        lbl_email.setForeground(Color.black);

        // Definição do posicionamento das caixas de texto
        txt_codigo = new JTextField();
        txt_codigo.setBounds(130, 30, 150, 20);
        getContentPane().add(txt_codigo);

        txt_nome = new JTextField("");
        txt_nome.setBounds(130, 60, 150, 20);
        getContentPane().add(txt_nome);

        txt_ende = new JTextField("");
        txt_ende.setBounds(130, 90, 150, 20);
        getContentPane().add(txt_ende);

        txt_tele = new JTextField("");
        txt_tele.setBounds(130, 120, 150, 20);
        getContentPane().add(txt_tele);

        txt_nasc = new JTextField("");
        txt_nasc.setBounds(130, 150, 150, 20);
        getContentPane().add(txt_nasc);

        txt_cpf = new JTextField();
        txt_cpf.setBounds(130, 180, 150, 20);
        getContentPane().add(txt_cpf);

        txt_carg = new JTextField("");
        txt_carg.setBounds(130, 210, 150, 20);
        getContentPane().add(txt_carg);

        txt_email = new JTextField("");
        txt_email.setBounds(130, 240, 150, 20);
        getContentPane().add(txt_email);

        // Definição do posicionamento dos botões
        btn_inserir = new JButton("Cadastrar");
        btn_inserir.setBounds(10, 320, 100, 30);
        getContentPane().add(btn_inserir);

        btn_alterar = new JButton("Alterar");
        btn_alterar.setBounds(120, 320, 100, 30);
        getContentPane().add(btn_alterar);

        btn_excluir = new JButton("Excluir");
        btn_excluir.setBounds(230, 320, 100, 30);
        getContentPane().add(btn_excluir);

        btn_consultar = new JButton("Consultar");
        btn_consultar.setBounds(340, 320, 100, 30);
        getContentPane().add(btn_consultar);

        // Posição do status
        lbl_status = new JLabel("Status:");
        lbl_status.setBounds(10, 280, 50,15);
        getContentPane().add(lbl_status);
        lbl_status.setForeground(Color.black);

        txt_status = new JLabel(this.status);
        txt_status.setForeground(Color.RED);
        txt_status.setBounds(10, 280, 200, 20);

        // Atribuindo eventos aos botões
        btn_inserir.addActionListener(this);
        btn_alterar.addActionListener(this);
        btn_excluir.addActionListener(this);
        btn_alterar.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Funcionarios tela;
        tela = new Funcionarios();
        tela.setVisible(true);
        tela.setResizable(false);
    }

    void LimpaCampos() {
        txt_codigo.setText("");
        txt_nome.setText("");
        txt_ende.setText("");
        txt_tele.setText("");
        txt_nasc.setText("");
        txt_cpf.setText("");
        txt_carg.setText("");
        txt_email.setText("");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent botao) {
        if(botao.getSource() == btn_inserir) {
            boolean ok;
            ok = gravaFuncionarios();
            if(ok) {
                LimpaCampos();
                txt_status.setText("Dados gravados.");
            }
            else {
                txt_status.setText("Erro ao gravar");
            }
        }
        if(botao.getSource() == btn_excluir) {
            boolean ok;
            ok = excluirFuncionarios();
            if(ok) {
                LimpaCampos();
                txt_status.setText("Registro excluído.");
            }
            else {
                txt_status.setText("Código não cadastrado.");
                LimpaCampos();
            }
        }

        if (botao.getSource()== btn_alterar) {
            boolean ok ;
            ok = alterarFuncionarios();
            if (ok){
                txt_status.setText("Registro Alterado");
            }else{
                txt_status.setText("Código não encontrado");
            }
            LimpaCampos();
        }
        if(botao.getSource() == btn_consultar ){
            boolean ok ;
            ok = consultaFuncionarios();
            if ( ok ){
                txt_status.setText("");
            }else{
                txt_status.setText("Código não cadastrado");
                LimpaCampos();
            }

        }

    }

    boolean gravaFuncionarios() {
        boolean ok = true;
        //int vCodigo = Integer.parseInt(txt_codigo.getText());
        String vNome = txt_nome.getText();
        String vEnde = txt_ende.getText();
        String vTele = txt_tele.getText();
        String vNasc = txt_nasc.getText();
        String vCPF = txt_cpf.getText();
        String vCargo = txt_carg.getText();
        String vEmail = txt_email.getText();

        String vSQL;
        vSQL = "INSERT INTO FUNCIONARIOS VALUES('"+ vNome +"', '"+ vEnde +"', '"+ vTele +"', '"+ vNasc +"', '"+ vCPF +"', '"+ vCargo +"', '"+ vEmail +"')";

        try {
            Statement st = conexao.createStatement();
            st.executeUpdate(vSQL);
        }
        catch(SQLException erro) {
            ok = false;
        }
        return ok;
    }

    boolean excluirFuncionarios() {
        boolean ok = true;

        int vCodigo = Integer.parseInt(txt_codigo.getText());

        String vSQL;
        vSQL = "DELETE FROM FUNCIONARIOS WHERE CodFunc=" + vCodigo;

        try {
            Statement st = conexao.createStatement();
            st.executeUpdate(vSQL);
        }
        catch(SQLException erro) {
            ok = false;
        }
        return ok;
    }

    boolean alterarFuncionarios() {
        boolean ok = true;
        int vCodigo = Integer.parseInt(txt_codigo.getText());
        String vNome = txt_nome.getText();
        String vEnde = txt_ende.getText();
        String vTele = txt_tele.getText();
        String vNasc = txt_nasc.getText();
        String vCPF = txt_cpf.getText();
        String vCargo = txt_carg.getText();
        String vEmail = txt_email.getText();

        String vSQL;
        vSQL = "UPDATE FUNCIONARIOS SET NomFunc='" + vNome + "', EndFunc='" + vEnde + "' TelFunc='" + vTele + "' NasFunc='" + vNasc + "' CPFFunc='" + vCPF + "' CgoFunc='" + vCargo + "' EmaFunc='" + vEmail + "'WHERE CodFunc=" + vCodigo;

        try {
            Statement st = conexao.createStatement();
            st.executeUpdate(vSQL);
        }
        catch(SQLException erro) {
            ok = false;
        }
        return ok;
    }

    boolean consultaFuncionarios(){
        boolean ok = true ;
        int vCodigo = Integer.parseInt(txt_codigo.getText());
        String sql; 

        sql = "SELECT * FROM FUNCIONARIOS WHERE CodFunc=" + vCodigo ;
        try{
            Statement st = conexao.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql) ;
            if (rs.next()){
                txt_nome.setText(rs.getString("NomFunc"));
                txt_ende.setText(rs.getString("EndFunc"));
                txt_tele.setText(rs.getString("TelFunc"));
                txt_nasc.setText(rs.getString("NasFunc"));
                txt_cpf.setText(rs.getString("CPFFunc"));
                txt_carg.setText(rs.getString("CgoFunc"));
                txt_email.setText(rs.getString("EmaFunc"));
            }else{
                ok = false ; 
            }
        }catch(Exception erro){
            ok = false ;
        }
        return ok ;
    }
}
```

Me ajudem por favor!!!!!! E obrigado.

Comment: 291 linhas de código. Isso não é grande não. Tomei a liberdade de editar e colocar o código aqui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu problema é que parece que você se esqueceu disso:

```java
    getContentPane().add(txt_status);
```

A ser colocado logo após isso:

```java
    txt_status = new JLabel(this.status);
    txt_status.setForeground(Color.RED);
    txt_status.setBounds(10, 280, 200, 20);
```

Além disso a posição deste Label na tela parece estar incorreta. Acho que deveria ser isso:

```java
    txt_status.setBounds(130, 280, 200, 15);
```

---

Para te ajudar, também devo dizer que seu programa têm vários outros problemas:

- SQL Injection.
- [Manipular componentes Swing fora da EDT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2017/aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-swing-por-que-o-m%C3%A9todo-main-deve-despachar-a-cria%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-gui-para-a-ed). Isso pode causar bugs difíceis de rastrear.
- Um `ActionListener` genérico ao invés de usar `ActionListener`s específicos. Isso tende a deixar o código confuso e difícil de se mexer.
- Mistura de código de acesso a dados com código de UI. Isso é uma má prática de programação.
- Nomenclatura de variáveis em desacordo com o padrão.
- Você utiliza campos com visibilidade de pacote. Raramente isso é o desejado. Acho que eles deveriam ser privados.
- Tratamento de exceções bem meia boca. Você mostra "Código não cadastrado" e "Código não encontrado" se o usuário não encontrou o que procurava ou se ocorreu um erro no acesso ao banco de dados. É importante distinguir estas duas situações para evitar que o usuário pense que a informação sumiu do sistema quando na verdade ocorreu um erro na conexão com o banco de dados.
- *Input kludge*: Se o usuário digitar um texto ao invés de um número no `txt_codigo`, vai estourar um `NumberFormatException`. Se ele digitar um texto grande demais para caber no banco de dados em alguns campos, vai estourar uma `SQLException` também.
- O campo `txt_codigo` talvez devesse ser somente-leitura, senão dá para bagunçar bastante com o seu banco de dados ao inserir valores arbitrários nele.
- Me parece que `Conectar.status` é uma variável global. E você deve saber que usar variáveis globais não é uma boa prática de programação.
- Ao fechar a janela, nada acontece. O sistema não encerra. Talvez você tenha colocado o código para fazer isso na superclasse `Janela`, mas pode ser que esteja em falta.

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, deu vontade de dar umas cabeçadas na parede agora, sou bem novo em java, valeu pelas dicas, vou pesquisar sobre todos os problemas e fazer o possível para desaparecer com eles. Mais uma vez, obrigado.

Comment: @WellingtonViana De nada. Qualquer dúvida, sempre haverá alguém aqui no StackOverflow para ajudar. :)

Comment: E o que seria código de UI? Pesquisei e não achei, rs

Comment: @WellingtonViana UI = User Interface. Ou seja, interface do usuário. No seu caso, Swing.

Comment: Entendi, valeu. E quanto à variável status, ela está nessa classe http://pastebin.com/YrNbbti9 ,o que seria recomendado eu usar ao invés de uma variável global?

Comment: Você pode querer instanciar a classe `Conexao` (e remover o modificador `abstract`) e colocar o `status` e o método `getConnection()` como sendo de instância ao invés de estáticos. Isso também vai te ajudar se a sua aplicação puder evoluir para ter duas ou mais conexões com o banco de dados (evoluir para isso quando ela já está grande é difícil, lhe digo por experiência própria). Se tiver certeza em ter apenas uma conexão sempre, você pode dar uma olhada no padrão de projeto Singleton.

Comment: Vou ver isso e, mais uma vez, obrigado, ajudou demais cara.