# jFrame congelado/travado quando abre em um jTable

Tags: java, swing, jframe

A ideia é clicar na linha da tabela que esta um jFrame1 e abrir outra jFrame2 com a busca das informações da pessoa baseada no RE, mas quando clico nele o código até funciona mas abre a janela congelada e travada.

O código pra listagem na jTable1 é esse:

```
public void PesquisarFuncionarios() {
    txtBusca.requestFocus();
    ArrayList dados = new ArrayList();
    String[] Colunas = new String[] {
        "RE/MAT", "NOME", "FUNÇÃO"
    };

    String sql = "Select REMAT,NOME,FUNCAO from funcionarios where NOME like ?";
    try {
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, txtBusca.getText() + "%");
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            dados.add(new Object[] {
                rs.getString("REMAT"), rs.getString("NOME"), rs.getString("FUNCAO")
            });
        }
    } catch (SQLException error) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERRO AO PESQUISAR" + error);
    }

    Listar modelo = new Listar(dados, Colunas);
    jListar.setModel(modelo);
    jListar.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(80);
    jListar.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);

    jListar.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(350);
    jListar.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);

    jListar.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(400);
    jListar.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);

    jListar.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    jListar.setAutoResizeMode(jListar.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    jListar.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
}

public void BuscarLinhas() {
    int selecionada = jListar.getSelectedRow();
    if (selecionada == -1) {
        return; //Não tem nada selecionado
    }
    setRemat(Integer.parseInt(jListar.getValueAt(selecionada, 0).toString()));
}
```

Mas agora no outro jframe2 não tem nenhum codigo, mas quando chama ele pra abrir com a variável do RE ele trava e tem que fechar finalizando o executar.

O jFrame1 inteiro:

```
package atestados;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import atestados.mysql;

import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author FU14855
*/


 public class Consultar extends javax.swing.JFrame {



Connection con;
PreparedStatement pst;
ResultSet rs;
private int remat;

/**
 * Creates new form Consultar
 */
     public Consultar() throws 
  ClassNotFoundException, 
 InstantiationException, 
 IllegalAccessException {

     initComponents();
     setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);//iniciar a tela no centro do monitor
    con = mysql.abrirConexao();
    PesquisarFuncionarios();
}

Consultar(CONSULTAS aThis, boolean b) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body      of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}


public void PesquisarFuncionarios() {
    txtBusca.requestFocus();
    ArrayList dados = new ArrayList();
    String[] Colunas = new String[]{"RE/MAT", "NOME", "FUNÇÃO"};

    String sql = "Select REMAT,NOME,FUNCAO from funcionarios where NOME like ?";
    try {
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, txtBusca.getText() + "%");
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            dados.add(new Object[]{rs.getString("REMAT"), 
   rs.getString("NOME"), rs.getString("FUNCAO")});

        }

    } catch (SQLException error) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERRO AO PESQUISAR" + error);

    }
    Listar modelo = new Listar(dados, Colunas);
    jListar.setModel(modelo);
    jListar.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(80);
    jListar.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);

    jListar.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(350);
    jListar.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);

    jListar.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(400);
    jListar.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);

    jListar.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    jListar.setAutoResizeMode(jListar.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    jListar.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

}

public void BuscarLinhas() {

    int selecionada = jListar.getSelectedRow();
    if (selecionada == -1) {
        return; //Não tem nada selecionado
    }
    setRemat(Integer.parseInt(jListar.getValueAt(selecionada, 0).toString()));

  //  System.out.println(getRemat());

}
public void ConsultarCad(String cid){
            CONSULTAS menuzin = new CONSULTAS(cid);
       this.dispose();
            menuzin.setVisible(true);

 }

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    txtBusca = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jListar = new javax.swing.JTable();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("CONSULTAR");

    jLabel1.setText("LOCALIZE O FUNCIONÁRIO PELO NOME:");

    jButton1.setText("CADASTRAR NOVO(A) FUNCIONARIO");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    txtBusca.setFocusCycleRoot(true);
    txtBusca.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            txtBuscaKeyReleased(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setText("VOLTAR");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jListar.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
        }
    ));
    jListar.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jListarMouseClicked(evt);
        }
        public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jListarMouseReleased(evt);
        }
    });
    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jListar);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.
     Alignment.TRAILING,layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2)
                .addComponent(txtBusca, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.
  Alignment.LEADING,layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
           .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.
   ComponentPlacement.RELATED,389, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1))
   .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING,layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
  .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jButton2)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 10, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(jButton1))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(txtBusca, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 513, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    cadastro cada = null;
    try {
        cada = new cadastro();
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Consultar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Consultar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    cada.show();
    setVisible(false);


}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    TelaAcesso tela = new TelaAcesso();

    tela.show();
    setVisible(false);
}                                        

private void txtBuscaKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     
    PesquisarFuncionarios();

}                                    

private void jListarMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      


}                                     

private void jListarMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    BuscarLinhas();
    ConsultarCad(String.valueOf(getRemat()));

}                                    

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Consultar.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Consultar.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Consultar.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
  java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Consultar.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level            .SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        try {
            new Consultar().setVisible(true);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Consultar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Consultar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Consultar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JTable jListar;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtBusca;
// End of variables declaration                   

/**
 * @return the remat
 */
public int getRemat() {
    return remat;
}

/**
 * @param remat the remat to set
 */
public void setRemat(int remat) {
    this.remat = remat;
}


/**
 * @return the remat
 */



  }
```

Comment: Onde está o `JFrame` nesse código?

Comment: isso é o metodo q contem no jFrame, vou postar ele inteiro

Comment: não é a sua consulta no 2º jframe que está travando a JVM?

Comment: Não faça operações de I/O ou de rede na EDT! http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/132

Answer (score 1):

**Vinicius**, pelo que entendi do seu código o que está acontecendo é o seguinte:

O `jFrame1` está sendo executado em uma [thread](http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/programacao-concorrente-e-threads/) específica, você então faz uma busca e cria uma lista de dados e então passa para o `jFrame2`.

Porém o `jFrame2` encontra-se em uma outra thread quando está exibindo, e, ao receber a lista, ele recebe a referência dessa lista criada no `jFrame1`. A partir dai você tem duas threads  tentando utilizar a lista de dados, o que provavelmente acarreta no travamento da janela.

**SOLUÇÃO**

Troque o `jFrame2` por um `JDialog` e seta a modalidade como true.

```
 JDialog dialog = new JDialog(parent, true);
```

Ou você cria uma classe que extenda o `JFrame` e ao mandar a lista pro `jFrame2`, você cria uma cópia da lista dentro do `jFrame2` antes de exibi-lo. Algo parecido com isso:

```
private void abrirDadosNoJFrame2(List dados){
      JFrameExtendido jFrame2 = new JFrameExtendido(dados);
      jFrame2.setVisible(true);
}
```

No construtor do `JFrameExtendido`:

```
private List listaDados;

public JFrameExtendido(List dados){
      initComponents();
      listaDados = new ArrayList(dados);
}
```