# Exceção no Java UiThreadingViolationException

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, look-and-feel

Eu fiz um projeto com o `LookAndFeel` `Substance`, nele eu tenho uma `thread` que fica atualizando periodicamente um `JProgressBar`, o problema é que na função `JProgressBar.setValue(1)` e `JProgressBar.setMaximum(10)` ocorre a excessão abaixo:

```
org.pushingpixels.substance.api.UiThreadingViolationException: Component state change must be done on Event Dispatch Thread
    at org.pushingpixels.substance.internal.utils.SubstanceCoreUtilities.testComponentStateChangeThreadingViolation(SubstanceCoreUtilities.java:2072)
    at org.pushingpixels.substance.internal.ui.SubstanceProgressBarUI$SubstanceChangeListener.stateChanged(SubstanceProgressBarUI.java:87)
    at javax.swing.JProgressBar.fireStateChanged(JProgressBar.java:729)
    at javax.swing.JProgressBar$ModelListener.stateChanged(JProgressBar.java:652)
    at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.fireStateChanged(DefaultBoundedRangeModel.java:364)
    at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.setRangeProperties(DefaultBoundedRangeModel.java:302)
    at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.setMaximum(DefaultBoundedRangeModel.java:219)
    at javax.swing.JProgressBar.setMaximum(JProgressBar.java:898)
```

Quero saber como posso corrigir esse problema, ou talvez como **suprimi-lo**, visto que não impacta no meu layout.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695247/substance-lf-not-working

Comment: @rrnan nessa pergunta ele diz que corrigiu colocando no `invokeLater()`, mas como faço isso, parece que esse método é pra construir a `thread` que roda a aplicação só que eu tenho outra pra atualizar o `component` então não sei como deveria ficar

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2017/aplica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-swing-por-que-o-m%c3%a9todo-main-deve-despachar-a-cria%c3%a7%c3%a3o-da-gui-para-a-ed?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O [Victor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/132/victor) me deu a dica nos comentários e eu fui atrás do [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2017/aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-swing-por-que-o-m%C3%A9todo-main-deve-despachar-a-cria%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-gui-para-a-ed?rq=1) que ele me passou, após me aprofundar em pesquisas consegui entender o problema com esse outro [link](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/invokelater.shtml).

Abaixo exemplo da classe que fiz pra atualizar meu `JProgressBar`. Notar que a mágica está no `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.

```
class AtualizaComponente implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (jProgressBar1.getValue() < jProgressBar1.getMaximum()) {
                        jProgressBar1.setValue(jProgressBar1.getValue() + 1);
                    } else {
                        jProgressBar1.setValue(0);
                    }
                }
            });
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```