# Atualizar (refresh) um JDialog (swing) dinamicamente

Tags: java, swing

Estou com alguns problemas ao atualizar o `JDialog` criado através do [`WindowsBuilder`](https://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) no Eclipse (não seria por conta disto).

Basicamente eu tenho uma tela de **Alterar Cadastros** do meu mini-sistema financeiro, eu carrego as informações na tela do usuário logado e exibo os demais em um `JComboBox`.

Criei um `ActionListener` para que quando o `JComboBox` for modificado, ele valide se o usuário selecionado é diferente do que está mostrando atualmente. Se for, ele carrega as novas informações.

Abaixo um trecho de código tentando explicar:

```java
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import br.com.base_classes_paper.cadastroBase;
import br.com.classes_paper.cadastroActions;


public class altCadastroUsuario1 extends JDialog {

    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    private JTextField txtLogin;
    private JTextField passSenha;
    public cadastroBase valCadBas;
    public ArrayList<cadastroBase> cadTotal;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            altCadastroUsuario1 dialog = new altCadastroUsuario1();
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public altCadastroUsuario1() {

        setTitle("PaperSys");
        setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPanel.setLayout(null);

        txtLogin = new JTextField();
        txtLogin.setBounds(106, 165, 260, 20);
        txtLogin.setText(valCadBas.getLogin());
        contentPanel.add(txtLogin);
        txtLogin.setColumns(10);

        passSenha = new JTextField();
        passSenha.setBounds(468, 165, 270, 20);
        passSenha.setText(valCadBas.getPass());
        contentPanel.add(passSenha);
        passSenha.setColumns(10);

        JComboBox jComBox_NomeUsuar = new JComboBox();

        for (cadastroBase load : cadTotal){
            jComBox_NomeUsuar.addItem(load.login);
        }

        jComBox_NomeUsuar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String selected = (String) jComBox_NomeUsuar.getSelectedItem();
                if (selected.equalsIgnoreCase(txtLogin.getText())){
                    for (cadastroBase load : cadTotal){
                        if (selected.equalsIgnoreCase(load.nomes)){
                            valCadBas.setLogin(load.login);
                            valCadBas.setPass(load.pass);
                            recarregarTela();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        });
        jComBox_NomeUsuar.setBounds(539, 282, 199, 20);
        contentPanel.add(jComBox_NomeUsuar);

    }
    protected void recarregarTela() {
        //altCadastroUsuario.this.removeAll();
        altCadastroUsuario1.this.repaint();
        altCadastroUsuario1.this.revalidate();
        //contentPanel.repaint();
        //contentPanel.revalidate();
    }

}
```

No caso, meu método faria mais ou menos o que está ai em cima, porém com alguns campos extras e métodos internos que rodam em outras classes. Mas do jeito que está, o mesmo não funciona.

Para ver se consigo me comunicar melhor: tenho a tela (gerada pelo windows builder do eclipse) que inicialmente exibe os dados do usuário que se logou no sistema (vamos supor login e senha) via get/set e as demais informações de todos os usuários do qual ele tem acesso salvo em um array carregando apenas os logins no jcombobox, dai quando ele modifica alguma casa no combobox eu valido se o que ele muda no jcombobox é diferente do que esta mostrando na tela, se sim eu carrego as informações deste usuário no get/set e tento dar o refresh da pagina pelos métodos      `revalidate()` e `repaint()` pelo qual não atualizam o cadastro (o java compilando executar ambos mas nada acontece a seguir). Caso necessitam do código inteiro eu disponho dele amanhã pois hoje não me encontro em casa.

Comment: Olá Giovan, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em português. Para que possamos te ajudar precisamos de um contexto maior sobre o que está acontecendo e o que não funciona. Crie um [mvce](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) e começamos a trabalhar daí.

Comment: Esse código nem roda, com erro de sintaxe. Tente testar o código postado antes de criar a questão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O melhor que consegui foi isso. Eu não sei o que ele deveria fazer exatamente ao recarregar a tela, portanto coloquei lá um `System.out.println` para demonstrar que o método foi chamado. Sempre que eu seleciono na `JComboBox` um nome igual ao da `JTextField`, esta função é chamada e o texto é escrito no console.

Eis o código:

```java
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class AltCadastroUsuario extends JDialog {
    private final JPanel contentPanel;

    protected String nome;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(AltCadastroUsuario::iniciar);
    }

    private static void iniciar() {
        try {
            AltCadastroUsuario dialog = new AltCadastroUsuario();
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setSize(400, 200);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public AltCadastroUsuario() {
        contentPanel = new JPanel();
        this.add(contentPanel);
        JTextField txtLogin = new JTextField();
        txtLogin.setText("Teste");
        contentPanel.add(txtLogin);

        JComboBox<String> jComBox_NomeUsuar = new JComboBox<>();
        jComBox_NomeUsuar.addItem("Pedro");
        jComBox_NomeUsuar.addItem("Carlos");
        contentPanel.add(jComBox_NomeUsuar);

        jComBox_NomeUsuar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String selected = (String) jComBox_NomeUsuar.getSelectedItem();
                if (selected.equalsIgnoreCase(txtLogin.getText())) {
                    nome = selected;
                    recarregarTela();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    protected void recarregarTela() {
        System.out.println("Recarregando");
        //altCadastroUsuario.this.removeAll();
        AltCadastroUsuario.this.repaint();
        AltCadastroUsuario.this.revalidate();
        //contentPanel.repaint();
        //contentPanel.revalidate();
    }
}
```

No seu código havia os seguintes problemas:

- Você estava usando `protect` ao invés de `protected`, isso causava um erro de compilação ([tal como revisado pelo Bruno César](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/58485/3)).
- Faltavam alguns *casts* ao usar o método `getSelectedItem()` da `JComboBox`. Isso também causava um erro de compilação.
- Você não deu a classe toda, o que obviamente torna o seu código não-compilável e deixa a sua questão mais difícil de ser respondida. Demorou algum tempo para eu perceber que `altCadastroUsuario` era o nome da classe. No entanto, eu não deveria ter que adivinhar isso sozinho. Além disso, nomes de classes deveriam iniciar com letras maiúsculas. Também tive que deduzir que `altCadastroUsuario` é subclasse de `JDialog`.
- [Não acesse o Swing fora da thread de eventos do AWT.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/132)
- Defina um tamanho padrão da janela antes de mostrá-la, para não vir uma janela de tamanho mínimo que sou obrigado a redimensionar para usar.
- O campo `nome` contém `null` quando o construtor da classe é iniciado. Como resultado, a `JTextField` tinha um tamanho tão ridiculamente pequeno, que ela não era usável.
- Você adicionava a `JComboBox` e a `JTextField` em um `JPanel`, mas não adicionava o `JPanel` à tela. O resultado é que vinha uma tela em branco!
- Vale a pena você dar uma investida em colocar um layout legal na sua `JPanel`. Do jeito que está, fica até difícil de se utilizar.
- Tal como já mencionei antes, não sei o que mais deveria ocorrer no `recarregarTela`. Coloquei lá um `System.out.println` só para provar que ele é chamado quando de fato deveria ser chamado.
- Se quiser deixar mais simples, caso esteja usando o Java 8 ou superior, use um lambda:

  ```
      jComBox_NomeUsuar.addActionListener(event -> {
          String selected = (String) jComBox_NomeUsuar.getSelectedItem();
          if (selected.equalsIgnoreCase(txtLogin.getText())) {
              nome = selected;
              recarregarTela();
          }
      });
  ```

---

A pergunta foi editada. Agora a minha sugestão é trocar este trecho:

```
                for (cadastroBase load : cadTotal){
                    if (selected.equalsIgnoreCase(load.nomes)){
                        valCadBas.setLogin(load.login);
                        valCadBas.setPass(load.pass);
                        recarregarTela();
                    }
                }
```

Por isso:

```
                for (cadastroBase load : cadTotal) {
                    if (selected.equalsIgnoreCase(load.nomes)) {
                        valCadBas.setLogin(load.login);
                        valCadBas.setPass(load.pass);
                        txtLogin.setText(load.login);
                        passSenha.setText(load.pass); // Isso só se você achar que faz sentido colocar a senha.
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

E com isso, o método `recarregarTela()` deixa de existir.

Comment: Como você está usando `method referece capture`, ao invés de usar uma classe anônima no listener considere usar lambda com um handler method, acredito ficaria mais "legível". Talvez também seja bom deixar claro que está usando java 8 =)

Comment: @BrunoCésar Feito.

Comment: Prezados bom dia,
Agradeço a ajuda, o código acima é apenas um esboço e desculpe não ter colocado todo, valido informações em conjunto com 5 classes nesta tela o que acaba dificultando um pouco a explicação do código, o que estou tentando fazer está no comentário de baixo para entender, mas na verdade seria um refresh na tela recarregando as informações.

Comment: Tenho a tela (gerada pelo windows builder do eclipse) que inicialmente exibe os dados do usuário que se logou no sistema (vamos supor login e senha) via get/set e carrego os outros usuários em um array passando para a tela apenas os logins no 'jcombobox', dai quando ele modifica alguma casa no combobox eu valido se o atual é diferente do mostrado na tela, se for eu carrego do array as informações deste usuario no get/set e tento dar o refresh da pagina com revalidate() e repaint() sem sucesso (o java compilando executa ambos os metodos mas nada acontece ao passar por eles).

Comment: @GiovanDias Tudo o que você tem que fazer é chamar os métodos `setText` (ou semelhantes) nos objetos adequados, provavelmente `JLabel`s e `JTextField`s. Não deveria ser necessário `revalidate()` e nem `repaint()`.

Comment: Olá Victor, Obrigado pelo retorno. Então, eu crio a tela e exibo os `JLabel`s e `JTextField`s com as informações do usuário que está logado no sistema, porém quando ele troca o usuário que está no `JComboBox` eu tenho que atualizar as informações mostradas nos `JTextField`s com os dados daquele outro usuário (para entender, eu, Giovan Me logo no sistema, quando carrego a tela ela já é criada com as minhas informações, mas eu quero alterar a senha do Victor que é outro usuário, então eu seleciono o nome dele no `JComboBox` e tenho que atualizar as informações da Tela) se fechar e reabrir a tela

Comment: @GiovanDias Sim, você pega essa informação que é o usuário selecionado, busca todos os dados necessário com ela, e então dá o `setText` em todos os campos pertinentes da tela.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Dei uma grande melhorada no código da postagem original só não repare nos icones espalhados no frame, eu ocultei os demais icones. Só para constar a classe cadastroBase tem os campos que a tela mostra (todos) e os métodos get/set que eu uso. Vale lembrar também que o arraylist desta tela foi adaptado, ele é salvo em outra tela e carrego as informações nela para não perder as informações caso a tela der refresh, mais uma ponto a ser observado, quando eu crio a tela que carrego as informações eu valido para que no refresh não carregue as mesmas informações!!!!!

Comment: @GiovanDias Editei minha resposta.

Comment: @VictorStafusa entendi a questão, porém estas informações são carregadas em uma segunda classes (não faço funções diretas nas telas, trabalho com 4 pacotes, 1 para telas, 1 para ações, 1 para bases e outro para banco de dados), ai é que está o método do refresh seria para fazer o que você está falando!

Comment: @GiovanDias Ok, mas em algum lugar você vai ter que chamar os métodos `setText()`, né?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Sim, a tea já faz isso automativamente nesta parte abaixo:
        _txtLogin.setText(valCadBas.getLogin());_
        contentPanel.add(txtLogin);

        _passSenha.setText(valCadBas.getPass());_
        contentPanel.add(passSenha);

Comment: @VictorStafusa Achei o erro e obrigado pela sua explicação!!!! Fiz um `setText()` mesmo e um `repaint()` e modificou, agora vou fazer uma função que set todos os valores de uma vez para reaproveitar o código e fazer quando crio e quando e atualizo o código!!!! Agradeço muito a explicação!!!!!!!!!!