# Alterar texto de uma JTextArea em tempo de execução

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

Bom dia a todos,

Tenho uma rotina de backup que deveria escrever o resultado em uma `JTextArea`, em tempo de execução.

A cópia funciona, o problema é que a janela que contém a `JTextArea` fica travada e não faz o append do texto toda vez que um arquivo ou diretório é copiado. Ele só escreve depois que a cópia termina por completo. Preciso que escreva o status arquivo a arquivo.

Alguém pode me ajudar? Seria de grande valia, já tem um tempo que estou quebrando a cabeça e não acho solução para problema semelhante na net. Obrigado.

Seguem os códigos:

```
private void executarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    Path origem = Paths.get("\\\\apolo\\sobe");
    Path destino = Paths.get("\\\\hermes\\DCPD\\BKP-SOBE\\teste5");

    try {
        jtaRetorno.append("Executando Cópia");
        Files.walkFileTree(origem, new CopyDir(origem, destino, jtaRetorno));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FrmExecutaCopia.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

A classe `CopyDir` tem o seguinte código:

```
public class CopyDir extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {
    private final Path origem;
    private final Path destino;
    private final JTextArea retorno;

    // Construtor com origem e destino
    public CopyDir(Path origem, Path destino, JTextArea retorno) {
        this.origem = origem;
        this.destino = destino;
        this.retorno = retorno;
    }

    // Usado para criar o diretorio
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
        throws IOException {
        copiaPath(dir);
        retorno.append("Diretorio "+dir.toString()+" criado.\n");
        System.out.println("Diretorio "+dir.toString()+" criado.\n");
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
    // Copia cada arquivo existente na arvore
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
        throws IOException {
        copiaPath(file);
        retorno.append("Arquivo "+file.toString()+" copiado.\n");
        System.out.println("Arquivo "+file.toString()+" copiado.\n");
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    // Metodo que efetivamente copia os arquivos
    private void copiaPath(Path entrada) throws IOException {
        // encontra o caminho equivalente na arvore de copia
        Path novoDiretorio = destino.resolve(origem.relativize(entrada));
        Files.copy(entrada, novoDiretorio);
    }
    /*
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Path origem = Paths.get("\\\\apolo\\sobe");
        Path destino = Paths.get("\\\\hermes\\DCPD\\BKP-SOBE\\teste");

        Files.walkFileTree(origem, new CopyDir(origem, destino, retorno));
    }
    */
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu problema é que você está manipulando arquivos dentro da EDT (*Event-Dispatching Thread*). Essa é a thread que o AWT e o Swing usam para renderizar a tela e procesar eventos de teclado e mouse, entre outras coisas do gênero. Uma vez que você faz esta thread engasgar ao ficar trabalhando com arquivos no disco (algo que é muuuuito lento), o AWT e o Swing engasgam. Como está tudo na mesma thread, o AWT e o Swing só voltarão a ter controle da EDT quando toda a sua manipulação de arquivos for terminada.

Você nunca deve fazer esse tipo de coisa na EDT, e sim em uma thread separada. Veja mais detalhes [nesta outra resposta minha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/132).

Dito isso, vamos tentar arrumar o seu código. Estou usando a sintaxe do Java 8. Me avise se você precisar disso obrigatoriamente para o Java 7, que eu daí eu dou uma adaptada:

```java
private void executarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    Path origem = Paths.get("\\\\apolo\\sobe");
    Path destino = Paths.get("\\\\hermes\\DCPD\\BKP-SOBE\\teste5");

    jtaRetorno.append("Executando Cópia");
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> copiaArquivos(origem, destino));
    t.start();
}

private void copiaArquivos(Path origem, Path destino) {
    try {
        Files.walkFileTree(origem, new CopyDir(origem, destino, this::imprimeStatus));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FrmExecutaCopia.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        imprimeStatus(ex.toString());
    }
}

private void imprimeStatus(String texto) {
    System.out.println(texto);
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> jtaRetorno.append(texto + "\n"));
}
```

```java
public class CopyDir extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {
    private final Path origem;
    private final Path destino;
    private final Consumer<String> retorno;

    // Construtor com origem e destino.
    public CopyDir(Path origem, Path destino, Consumer<String> retorno) {
        this.origem = origem;
        this.destino = destino;
        this.retorno = retorno;
    }

    // Usado para criar o diretório.
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
            throws IOException
    {
        copiaPath(dir);
        retorno.accept("Diretório " + dir.toString() + " criado.");
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    // Copia cada arquivo existente na árvore.
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
            throws IOException
    {
        copiaPath(file);
        retorno.accept("Arquivo " + file.toString() + " copiado.");
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    // Método que efetivamente copia os arquivos.
    private void copiaPath(Path entrada) throws IOException {
        // Encontra o caminho equivalente na árvore de cópia.
        Path novoDiretorio = destino.resolve(origem.relativize(entrada));
        Files.copy(entrada, novoDiretorio);
    }

    /*
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path origem = Paths.get("\\\\apolo\\sobe");
        Path destino = Paths.get("\\\\hermes\\DCPD\\BKP-SOBE\\teste");

        Files.walkFileTree(origem, new CopyDir(origem, destino, System.out::println));
    }
    */
}
```

A ideia é:

- Nunca deixar a EDT mexer diretamente com arquivos, e por causa disso eu crio uma outra thread para esta finalidade.
- Esta outra thread nunca deve acessar o Swing diretamente, incluindo o `JTextArea`, pois o Swing não é *thread-safe*. Ao invés disso, eu uso o método [`EventQueue.invokeLater`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-) para que esta outra thread poste uma tarefa a ser executada pelo Swing, passando apenas uma `String` entre uma thread e outra.
- Eu uso o [`Consumer<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) do Java 8 como um objeto aonde a thread postará `String`s. No lado do chamador, ele redireciona isso ao método `imprimeStatus` que é responsável por chamar o `EventQueue.invokeLater`.
- A sua classe `CopyDir` fica agora totalmente desacoplada do Swing.

Comment: Ótimo. Deu certo! Obrigado. Vlw mesmo Victor.