# Erro ao inserir dados com o Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Estou tendo umo erro ao inserir no meu banco de dados:

> ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'de Admissao, Data de Demissao, Nome, Estado Civil, Sexo, CEP, CPF, RG, Data de N' at line 1
>   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement.

Eis o meu POJO:

```
public class Funcionario implements Serializable {



    private Integer iDFuncionario;
    private Date datadeAdmissao;
    private Date datadeDemissao;
    private String nome;
    private String estadoCivil;
    private String sexo;
    private String cep;
    private String cpf;
    private String rg;
    private String datadeNascimento;
    private String estado;
    private String cidade;
    private String bairro;
    private String endereco;
    private String tel;
    private String cel;
    private String email;
    private String cargo;
    private String niveldeEscolaridade;

     public Funcionario(String nome) {
      this.nome=nome;

    }


    public Funcionario(Integer iDFuncionario) {
     this.iDFuncionario=iDFuncionario;
    }

    public Integer getiDFuncionario() {
        return iDFuncionario;
    }


    public void setiDFuncionario(Integer iDFuncionario) {
        this.iDFuncionario = iDFuncionario;
    }

    public Date getDatadeAdmissao() {
        return datadeAdmissao;
    }

    public void setDatadeAdmissao(Date datadeAdmissao) {
        this.datadeAdmissao = datadeAdmissao;
    }

    public Date getDatadeDemissao() {
        return datadeDemissao;
    }

    public void setDatadeDemissao(Date datadeDemissao) {
        this.datadeDemissao = datadeDemissao;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEstadoCivil() {
        return estadoCivil;
    }

    public void setEstadoCivil(String estadoCivil) {
        this.estadoCivil = estadoCivil;
    }

    public String getSexo() {
        return sexo;
    }

    public void setSexo(String sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }

    public String getCep() {
        return cep;
    }

    public void setCep(String cep) {
        this.cep = cep;
    }

    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public String getRg() {
        return rg;
    }

    public void setRg(String rg) {
        this.rg = rg;
    }

    public String getDatadeNascimento() {
        return datadeNascimento;
    }

    public void setDatadeNascimento(String datadeNascimento) {
        this.datadeNascimento = datadeNascimento;
    }

    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public String getCidade() {
        return cidade;
    }

    public void setCidade(String cidade) {
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }

    public String getBairro() {
        return bairro;
    }

    public void setBairro(String bairro) {
        this.bairro = bairro;
    }

    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public String getTel() {
        return tel;
    }

    public void setTel(String tel) {
        this.tel = tel;
    }

    public String getCel() {
        return cel;
    }

    public void setCel(String cel) {
        this.cel = cel;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getCargo() {
        return cargo;
    }

    public void setCargo(String cargo) {
        this.cargo = cargo;
    }

    public String getNiveldeEscolaridade() {
        return niveldeEscolaridade;
    }

    public void setNiveldeEscolaridade(String niveldeEscolaridade) {
        this.niveldeEscolaridade = niveldeEscolaridade;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (iDFuncionario != null ? iDFuncionario.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Funcionario)) {
            return false;
        }
        Funcionario other = (Funcionario) object;
        if ((this.iDFuncionario == null && other.iDFuncionario != null) || (this.iDFuncionario != null && !this.iDFuncionario.equals(other.iDFuncionario))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Classes.Funcionario[ iDFuncionario=" + iDFuncionario + " ]";
    }

}
```

Eis o meu mapeamento da classe:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="Classes.Funcionario" table="funcionario" >
  <id name="iDFuncionario" column="ID_Funcionario">
      <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
        <property name="datadeAdmissao" type="date" length ="50" column="Data de Admissao" />
        <property name="datadeDemissao" type="date" length ="50" column="Data de Demissao"/>
        <property name="nome" type="string" length="50" column="Nome"/>
        <property name="estadoCivil" type="string" length="50" column="Estado Civil"/>
        <property name="sexo" type="string" length ="50" column="Sexo"/>
        <property name="cep" type="string" length ="50" column="CEP"/>
        <property name="cpf" type="string" length ="50" column="CPF"/>
        <property name="rg" type="string" length ="50" column="RG"/>
        <property name="datadeNascimento" type="string" length ="50" column="Data de Nascimento"/>
        <property name="estado" type="string" length ="50" column="Estado"/>
        <property name="cidade" type="string" length ="50" column="Cidade"/>
        <property name="bairro" type="string" length ="50" column="Bairro" />
        <property name="endereco" type="string" length ="50" column="Endereco"/>
        <property name="tel" type="string" length ="50" column="TEL"/>
        <property name="cel" type="string" length ="50" column="CEL"/>
        <property name="email" type="string" length ="50" column="Email"/>
        <property name="cargo" type="string" length ="50" column="Cargo"/>
        <property name="niveldeEscolaridade" type="string" length ="50" column="Nivel de Escolaridade"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Eis a minha classe `HibernateUtil`:

```
package Hibernate;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;




/**
 * Hibernate Utility class with a convenient method to get Session Factory
 * object.
 *
 * @author Douglas
 */
public class HibernateUtil {

   private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            // loads configuration and mappings
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("Hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml");
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry
                = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

            // builds a session factory from the service registry
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);           
        }

        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

E aqui, parte do código da minha tela de funcionários:

```
private String nome;


 String nome=Txt_Nome.getText();



      SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

      Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();


      Funcionario f1=new Funcionario(nome);




      session.beginTransaction();
      session.save(f1);
      session.getTransaction().commit();
      session.close();
```

Comment: O nome das colunas no banco de dados estão assim mesmo, com espaços, tal como "*Data de Admissao*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema parece ser os espaços nos nomes das colunas. Se o seu banco de dados contém colunas com espaços nos nomes, use o **`** para escapá-los.

Ou seja, o seu XML fica assim:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="Classes.Funcionario" table="funcionario" >
  <id name="iDFuncionario" column="ID_Funcionario">
      <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
        <property name="datadeAdmissao" type="date" length ="50" column="`Data de Admissao`" />
        <property name="datadeDemissao" type="date" length ="50" column="`Data de Demissao`"/>
        <property name="nome" type="string" length="50" column="`Nome`"/>
        <property name="estadoCivil" type="string" length="50" column="`Estado Civil`"/>
        <property name="sexo" type="string" length ="50" column="`Sexo`"/>
        <property name="cep" type="string" length ="50" column="`CEP`"/>
        <property name="cpf" type="string" length ="50" column="`CPF`"/>
        <property name="rg" type="string" length ="50" column="`RG`"/>
        <property name="datadeNascimento" type="string" length ="50" column="`Data de Nascimento`"/>
        <property name="estado" type="string" length ="50" column="`Estado`"/>
        <property name="cidade" type="string" length ="50" column="`Cidade`"/>
        <property name="bairro" type="string" length ="50" column="`Bairro`" />
        <property name="endereco" type="string" length ="50" column="`Endereco`"/>
        <property name="tel" type="string" length ="50" column="`TEL`"/>
        <property name="cel" type="string" length ="50" column="`CEL`"/>
        <property name="email" type="string" length ="50" column="`Email`"/>
        <property name="cargo" type="string" length ="50" column="`Cargo`"/>
        <property name="niveldeEscolaridade" type="string" length ="50" column="`Nivel de Escolaridade`"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Além disso, vejo que você está manipulando o banco de dados de dentro da thread dedicada do AWT/Swing. Isso não é algo bom de se fazer. Veja [essa minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/97356/132) para entender o porquê.

Comment: Nossa cara valeu funcionou não sabia dessas ai do ` nas colunas pensei que ia sem mesmo já o resto como é projeto final de curso tecnico já basta por enquanto fazer desse jeito

Comment: @DouglasLopes Se a minha resposta te serviu e não restou mais nenhuma dúvida, peço que marque-a como aceita/correta ao clicar no ✅ verde aqui ao lado, abaixo dos números da pontuação/votação. Obrigado.