# Clicar na tela e alterar os valores das variáveis

Tags: java, swing

Eu preciso implementar no código funcionalidades para que quando eu clique na tela, seja alterado os valores de algumas variáveis que estão no código. Entretanto, quando eu clico continua igual.

Minha [classe principal](http://pastebin.com/m3QGVgt4):

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Interface;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author Pessoal
 */
public class Interface extends JFrame implements MouseListener{
    static Point p = new Point();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame j = new JFrame("Interface");
        InterfaceClasse ic = new InterfaceClasse();
        j.add(ic);
        j.setSize(1300, 768);
        j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        j.setVisible(true);
        j.setResizable(false);

        ic.setTemperatura(30.0f);
        ic.setTensao(24.0f);
        ic.setVelocidade(10.0f);

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        InterfaceClasse ic = new InterfaceClasse();
        p=getMousePosition();
        if(p.x>=50 && p.x <=350 && p.y>=284 && p.y<=484){
        ic.setTensao(20.0f);
        ic.setTemperatura(25.5f);
        ic.setVelocidade(3.5f);
            System.out.println("Deu certo");
        }
        if(p.x>=950 && p.x <=1250 && p.y>=284 && p.y<=484){
        ic.setTensao(27.0f);
        ic.setTemperatura(33.5f);
        ic.setVelocidade(14.0f);
            System.out.println("Deu certo");
        }
        if(p.x>=500 && p.x <=800 && p.y>=50 && p.y<=250){
        ic.setTensao(24.0f);
        ic.setTemperatura(35.5f);
        ic.setVelocidade(10.0f);
            System.out.println("Deu certo");
        }
        if(p.x>=500 && p.x <=800 && p.y>=518 && p.y<=718){
        ic.setTensao(17.0f);
        ic.setTemperatura(17.3f);
        ic.setVelocidade(2.0f);
            System.out.println("Deu certo");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

Minha [outra classe](http://pastebin.com/9AmV7LVD):

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Interface;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author Pessoal
 */
public class InterfaceClasse extends JPanel{
    private float temperatura, velocidade, tensao;
    JLabel j;

    public InterfaceClasse(){
        int width, height;
        j = new JLabel("Temperatura");
        this.setSize(1200, 800);
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(new Color(43,132,156));
        g2d.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        g2d.drawString("Velocidade: ", 30, 20);
        String vel = Float.toString(velocidade);
        g2d.drawString(vel, "Velocidade: ".length()*10 + 15, 20);
        g2d.drawString("Temperatura: ", 30, 60);
        String temp = Float.toString(temperatura);
        g2d.drawString(temp, "Temperatuda: ".length() *11+10, 60);
        g2d.drawString("Tensão de entrada: ", 30, 100);
        String tens = Float.toString(tensao);
        g2d.drawString(tens, "Tensao de entrada: ".length() *10+10, 100);
    }

    public float getTemperatura() {
        return temperatura;
    }

    public void setTemperatura(float temperatura) {
        this.temperatura = temperatura;
    }

    public float getVelocidade() {
        return velocidade;
    }

    public void setVelocidade(float velocidade) {
        this.velocidade = velocidade;
    }

    public float getTensao() {
        return tensao;
    }

    public void setTensao(float tensao) {
        this.tensao = tensao;
    }

}
```

Estou com dúvidas em como posso alterar e resolver isso.

Comment: Adicione o código diretamente na pergunta, alguns podem não ter acesso aos links.

Answer (score 2):

Essa pergunta é antiga, está abandonada e é mal formulada, mas ainda assim é respondível. O problema é que basicamente há duas variáveis chamadas `ic`.

O `ic` de dentro do `main` é o que é renderizado na `JFrame`. No método `mouseClicked`, um outro `ic` é criado, alterado e nada é feito com ele, deixando-o com o coletor de lixo e deixando o `ic` original inalterado.

A solução seria transformar ambos os `ic`s em uma única variável de instância da classe `Interface` e instanciá-lo apenas uma vez (ou seja, não instanciá-lo dentro do `mouseClicked`).

Além disso, dar nomes de classes como `Interface` e `ClasseInterface` dentro de um pacote chamado `Interface` é uma péssima ideia, esses são uns dos piores nomes possíveis.

Os demais métodos referentes a mouse não deveriam lançar `UnsupportedOperationException` - isso é algo muito prejudicial (mesmo sendo algo gerado automaticamente pela IDE). Esses métodos deveriam apenas não fazer nada.

A variável `Point` não precisa ser estática. E nem de instância. Deveria ser uma variável local ao método `mouseClicked`.

Quanto a implementação do `main`, não poso deixar de me referir a [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2017/132) - Não manipule componentes Swing dentro da thread principal do programa.

Além disso, lembre-se de identar o código adequadamente para evitar confusão. Os blocos `if` dentro do método `mouseClicked` têm várias linhas de seu corpo com um nível de identação a menos.