# Interromper laço em java

Tags: java, swing, loop

Meu projeto em Java é um controle de farol com Arduíno. Até ai tudo certo. Porém fiz uma função na qual que os leds fica automático em um loop após um `RadionButton` ser selecionado. Meu problema é que quando eu seleciono o `RadionButton` meu `JFrame` congela e não deixa eu tirar a seleção do `RadionButton`.

Ou seja selecionar o botão causa um loop ativo. A ideia seria ao desmarcar o botão, fazer o loop parar.

Segue meu código.

Aqui é onde o botão será selecionado e enviará o comando para a função:

```
        if ( teste.isSelected() ) {
        try {
            utiArduino.enviarDados( "automatico" );
        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Jframe_farol.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } else {
        try {
            utiArduino.enviarDados( "DesligaAuto" );
        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Jframe_farol.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Aqui é a função do loop:

```
  public void enviarDados(String status) throws InterruptedException, IOException{
   int i = 8;

    if ( "automatico".equals(status) ) { // caso do automatico   
        while ( true ) {
            output.write(i);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            i++;
            if ( i > 10 ){
                i = 8;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Leia isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/132 - Esse `Thread.sleep(1000)` deve estar sendo feito na thread do AWT.

Comment: Além do que o @VictorStafusa disse, eu também acho que a abordagem de checar se o componente está setado para interromper o loop não está correta, há listeners para fazer esse tipo de monitoramento. Só fica dificil até sugerir uma alternativa com o trecho de código passado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O AWT e o Swing tem uma thread que gerencia o seu funcionamento, ela é chamada de *Event Dispatch Thread* - EDT. Como ela é uma thread única, se você fizer ela cair em um `while (true)` e/ou em um `Thread.sleep(1000)`, a interface gráfica ficará congelada.

Assim sendo, a solução é mover essas coisas para uma thread distinta. Tente fazer assim na sua classe `utiArduino`:

```
private volatile String ultimoStatus;
private volatile Thread threadArduino;

public void enviarDados(String status) {
   ultimoStatus = status;
   if (threadArduino == null) {
       threadArduino = new Thread(this::iniciarEnvioArduino);
       threadArduino.start();
   }
}

private void envioArduino() {
    int i = 8;
    try {
        while (Thread.currentThread() == threadArduino) {
            if ("automatico".equals(ultimoStatus)) { // caso do automatico   
                output.write(i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                i++;
                if (i > 10) i = 8;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // Não faz nada e deixa a thread morrer.
    }
}

public void parar() {
    if (threadArduino != null) {
        Thread t = threadArduino;
        threadArduino = null;
        t.interrupt();
    }
}
```

A seleção do seu botão fica assim:

```
utiArduino.enviarDados(teste.isSelected() ? "automatico" : "DesligaAuto");
```

Na sua subclasse de `JFrame` (que suponha que seja quem tem a referência `utiArduino`), coloque isso também:

```
@Override
public void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    utiArduino.parar();
}
```

Para mais informações sobre a EDT, dê uma lida [nessa minha outra resposta também.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/132)

Comment: Primeiramente Obrigado por ter respondido minha pergunta , Porém  a solução que você responde , ta com alguns erros, primeiro nesse trecho de código ' super.dispose();'  ta com seguinte error  'cannot find symbol  symbol: method dispose()' ,  o próximo erro é na linha   'threadArduino = new Thread(this::iniciarEnvioArduino);' , esta com seguinte error  ,  'method references are not supported in -source 1.7 (use -source 8 or higher to enable method references)
 method reference not expected here'   e o método envioArduino() não esta sendo usada você Pode me ajuda??  POR FAVOR

Comment: @JeffersonSantos Qual é a classe que contém a variável `utiArduino`? Qual é o tipo dessa variável? O seu primeiro erro indica que não eram as classes que eu estava imaginando que fossem, mas isso não está claro em sua pergunta. O segundo problema é algo de configuração, pois ele significa que você está usando o compilador do Java 8 para compilar Java 7, e não compilar Java 8 mesmo, e o meu código é Java 8. Edite a pergunta para complementar com essas informações.

Comment: Obg eu irei editar a pergunta, mas @VitcorStafusa  a 'utiArduino' não é  uma variável  é o nome da classe que contem o método enviarDados,   mas irei editar  a pergunta

Comment: @JeffersonSantos A classe `utiArduino` tem alguma superclasse? Se sim, qual? Qual é a classe que contém a chamada `utiArduino.enviarDados( "automatico" );`?

Comment: Boa noite @VictorStafusa a 'utiArduino' é uma classe simples nela contem a conexão , e o metodo  utiArduino.enviarDados( "automatico" ); , ou seja no meu Jframe principal eu instancio essa classa e ultilizo o método  utiArduino.enviarDados( "automatico" );  desculpe  o modo de tenta explica o problema ,  sera que pode me ajuda?

Comment: @JeffersonSantos A chamada `utiArduino.enviarDados( "automatico" );` está dentro de uma classe que herda de `JFrame`? Se sim, qual é o nome dela?

Comment: @JeffersonSantos Editei a resposta. Veja se assim dá certo. Se não der, me explique o que deu errado.

Comment: OI Vitor obg por tira seu tempo pra me ajuda, porém o erro que ta dando agora é sobre configuração iguam mesmo vc tinha mensionado vc sabe fazrr isso ou podr aonde eu começo  o fabor?

Comment: @JeffersonSantos Quanto a configuração, depende se você está usando Netbeans, Eclipse ou outra coisa. Mas nesse caso, recomendo a você criar uma pergunta nova acerca desse problema de configuração, pois isso já seria um problema bem diferente do que este que você apresentou nesta pergunta aqui, além de ser algo que você vai achar mais gente capaz de responder rapidamente.