# Qual a diferença entre usar SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable) e EventQueue.invokeLater(Runnable) ao invocar uma janela?

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

Estava lendo [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/28595) onde fala a respeito do uso da [EDT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/event-dispatch-thread/info) para manipular componentes do swing, mas lá é sugerido utilizar um dos dois métodos citados para "despachar" a interface para a EDT.

Existe diferença entre se utilizar [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-) ou  [`EventQueue.invokeLater(Runnable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-)? Há situação onde é melhor utilizar um ou outro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não há **nenhuma** diferença. O `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)` apenas encaminha ao `EventQueue.invokeLater(Runnable)` de forma direta.

Veja isso [diretamente do código-fonte da classe `SwingUtilities` da JDK](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/9a7384107eeb/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.java#l1414):

> ```
> public static void invokeLater(Runnable doRun) {
>     EventQueue.invokeLater(doRun);
> }
> ```