# Formatar texto de JLabel com cores diferentes

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Como eu poderia formatar com "propriedades" diferentes um `JLabel` e o seu conteúdo?

Por exemplo, eu queria poder setar uma cor pro texto do meu `JLabel`, e outra pra `string` que esta concatenada com ele. É possível?

No meu caso, ele ficou de um "jeito" só, e o `html` que eu tentei usar, também não deu certo.

O que eu tentei:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Teste extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Teste().setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel painel = new JPanel();

    private Font fonte = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 15);
    private JLabel label = new JLabel();

    private String string = "string";

    public Teste() {

        setSize(500, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        painel.add(label);
        add(painel);

        label.setText("Label + " + "<html><font color=#166B44> " + string + " </font></html>");
        label.setFont(fonte);
        label.setForeground(Color.red);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possível fazer isso usando `JLabel`, esse componente é para texto puro. Claro que ele aceita tags HTML para formatação de texto, mas além de "emporcalhar" o código, vai tornar bem difícil a manutenção depois.

Felizmente existem alternativas de componentes para este fim, que é o caso do [`JTextPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html) ou [`JEditorPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html), que aceitam estilização de texto, mesmo que fragmentados, como você precisa.

Veja este exemplo:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class JTextPaneExample {

    public void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("JTextPaneExample");

        // cria um StyleContext e um Document para o jtextpane
        StyleContext sc = new StyleContext();
        final DefaultStyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument(sc);
        JTextPane pane = new JTextPane(doc);
        pane.setEditable(false);

        // cria um estilo e adiciona atributos personalizados nele
        final Style redStyle = sc.addStyle("RED", null);
        redStyle.addAttribute(StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.red);
        redStyle.addAttribute(StyleConstants.FontSize, new Integer(16));

        final Style blueStyle = sc.addStyle("BLUE", null);
        blueStyle.addAttribute(StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.blue);
        blueStyle.addAttribute(StyleConstants.FontSize, new Integer(14));
        blueStyle.addAttribute(StyleConstants.Bold, new Boolean(true));

        try {
            // insere um texto inicial com uma style
            doc.insertString(0, "Texto inicial ", redStyle);
            // insere texto concatenado com outra style
            doc.insertString(pane.getText().length(), "texto concatenado", blueStyle);
        } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        f.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(pane));
        f.setSize(400, 300);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new JTextPaneExample().createAndShowGUI();;
        });
    }
}
```

Que resulta em:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Um [`StyleContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyleContext.html) é nada mais que um *pool* de estilos, onde adicionaremos os estilos que usaremos no componente. O [`DefaultStyledDocument`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultStyledDocument.html) é a classe que interpretará estes estilos e aplicará ao texto, conforme concatenamos e passamos os estilos para os fragmentos de textos. A interface [`Style`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Style.html) é o estilo em si, onde configuramos detalhes como cor, tamanho e tipo de fonte que queremos do texto.

---

**Referências**:

- [JTextPane Styles Example 1 : TextPane « Swing JFC « Java](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/JTextPaneStylesExample1.htm)
- [Different font color in a JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24104997/5524514)
- [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html)

Answer (score 2):

Para o efeito que você quer funcionar. Todo o texto do `JLabel` tem que estar dentro do `<html>...</html>`. Qualquer coisa que você coloque fora disso vai dar errado.

Por exemplo:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TesteCor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(TesteCor::executar);
    }

    public static void executar() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();

        Font fonte = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 15);
        JLabel label = new JLabel();

        frame.setSize(500, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        painel.add(label);
        frame.add(painel);

        label.setText(""
                + "<html>"
                + "Cor padrão "
                + "<font color=\"red\">Vermelho</font> "
                + "<font color=\"blue\">Azul</font> "
                + "<font color=\"green\">Verde</font> "
                + "<font color=\"yellow\">Amarelo</font> "
                + "</html>");
        label.setFont(fonte);
        label.setForeground(Color.pink);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Observe que coloquei o `Color.pink` como o *foreground* do label.

Quanto ao `EventQueue.invokeLater`, veja [essa minha outra resposta que o explica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/132).

Eis o resultado:

[image: Tela resultante]