# Criando componente JTextPane dinamico

Tags: java, swing

Eu tinha um problema com edição de `labels`, que foi solucionado com a utilização do `JTextPane`.

Então, eu pensei em criar meu próprio componente deste tipo, para que eu possa passar valores "dinamicamente", e escrevendo poucas linhas, tornando - o mais orientado a objetos. Porém, acredito que a minha lógica não esta muito correta, pois não consegui alterar o componente como na resposta que eu me baseie: [Formatar label + conteúdo separados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/226907/formatar-label-conte%c3%bado-separados) .

Seria o problema o jeito com o qual eu tentei usar o método do componente? :

```
 campo.setText(campo.formatar("Texto", "" + string, 0)); //aplicar o método do componente
```

Eu tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument;
import javax.swing.text.Style;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;

public class JTextPaneExample {

    private String string = "10";

    public void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("JTextPaneExample");

        MeuCampoJTextPane campo = new MeuCampoJTextPane();

        f.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(campo));
        campo.setText(campo.formatar("Texto", "" + string, 0)); //aplicar o método do componente  

        f.setSize(400, 300);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new JTextPaneExample().createAndShowGUI();

        });
    }
}

class MeuCampoJTextPane extends JTextPane {

    // cria um StyleContext e um Document para o jtextpane
    StyleContext sc = new StyleContext();
    final DefaultStyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument(sc);

    // cria um estilo e adiciona atributos personalizados nele
    final Style redStyle = sc.addStyle("RED", null);
    final Style blueStyle = sc.addStyle("BLUE", null);

    public MeuCampoJTextPane() {

        this.setEditable(false);

    }

    public String formatar(String texto, String valor, int tipo) {
        String stringFormatada = "";

        try {
            switch (tipo) {
                case 0:
                    blueStyle.addAttribute(StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.blue);
                    blueStyle.addAttribute(StyleConstants.FontSize, 14);
                    blueStyle.addAttribute(StyleConstants.Bold, true);
                    doc.insertString(0, texto, blueStyle);

                    DecimalFormat formatoDecimal2 = new DecimalFormat("## 00");
                    String d2 = formatoDecimal2.format(Float.valueOf(valor));
                    redStyle.addAttribute(StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.red);
                    redStyle.addAttribute(StyleConstants.FontSize, 12);
                    doc.insertString(this.getText().length(), d2, redStyle);
                    stringFormatada = d2;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return stringFormatada;
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: O fato de usar um componente personalizado em nada tem a ver com ser "orientado a objeto".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você está extendendo seu componente do JTextPane isso te dá acesso aos métodos dele dentro da classe. Desse modo, você poderia usar o setText() dentro do seu método formatar mas isso não é necessário pois ao setar o doc ele se encarrega de trocar o texto.

```
class MeuCampoJTextPane extends JTextPane {

// cria um StyleContext e um Document para o jtextpane
private StyleContext sc = new StyleContext();
private final DefaultStyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument(sc);

// cria um estilo e adiciona atributos personalizados nele
private final Style redStyle = sc.addStyle("RED", null);
private final Style blueStyle = sc.addStyle("BLUE", null);

public MeuCampoJTextPane() {
    redStyle.addAttribute(StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.red);
    redStyle.addAttribute(StyleConstants.FontSize, 12);
    blueStyle.addAttribute(StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.blue);
    blueStyle.addAttribute(StyleConstants.FontSize, 14);
    blueStyle.addAttribute(StyleConstants.Bold, true);
}

public void formatar(String texto, String valor, int tipo) {
    setStyledDocument(doc);
    setEditable(false);

    try {
        switch (tipo) {
            case 0:
                DecimalFormat formatoDecimal2 = new DecimalFormat("## 00");
                String d2 = formatoDecimal2.format(Float.valueOf(valor));
                doc.insertString(0, texto, blueStyle);
                doc.insertString(getText().length(), d2, redStyle);
                break;
            case 1:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Dessa forma o uso ficaria assim:

```
MeuCampoJTextPane campo = new MeuCampoJTextPane();
f.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(campo));
campo.formatar("Texto", "" + string, 0); //aplicar o método do componente
```