# Como deixar parte do texto JLabel em negrito

Tags: java, swing, formatação, jlabel

Há alguma forma de deixar apenas uma parte do texto em negrito de uma JLabel?

Por exemplo:

```java
label.setText("apenas esta parte em <b>negrito</b>");
```

Porém esse trecho de código imprime o 'b' na tela também.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa envolver o texto todo entre as tags `<html>` e `</html>`:

```
label.setText("<html>apenas esta parte em <b>negrito</b></html>");
```

Entretanto, sugiro usar componentes alternativos, que permitem fazer isso sem sujar o código com esses trechos html's avulsos: [`JTextPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html) ou [`JEditorPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html). [**Nesta resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/226914/28595) há um exemplo de uso de um destes componentes e do que eles são capazes de fazer.

Comment: Obrigado, não imaginava que seria tão simples

Comment: @P.Dominges sim, mas é bom utilizar apenas para casos esporádicos, uma vez que esses trechos em excesso tornam dificil a legibilidade e manutenção do código.