# Posicionar botões acimada tabela usando gerenciador de layouts

Tags: java, swing, layout

Eu estou tendo problemas posicionar componentes. Eu tenho uma tabela, e 3 botões, e eu estou tentando posicionar os botões acima da tabela de maneira centralizada.

Exemplo: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tentei usar o `FlowLayout`, e o resultado foi esse:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class PosicionaTabela extends JFrame {

    public PosicionaTabela() {

        Tabela tab = new Tabela();
        add(tab);
        setSize(700, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PosicionaTabela().setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Tabela extends JPanel {

    private JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane();

    private JTable tabela = new JTable();

    private JButton botao1 = new JButton("1");
    private JButton botao2 = new JButton("2");
    private JButton botao3 = new JButton("3");

    public Tabela() {
        confgTabela();
    }

    private JComponent confgTabela() {
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        jsp.setViewportView(tabela);
        jsp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        add(jsp);
        add(botao1);
        add(botao2);
        add(botao3);
        return painel;
    }
}
```

Comment: E qual a dificuldade?

Comment: eu não consigo colocar acima da tabela e centralizado, só do lado.

Comment: Apenas vendo a figura sem nem analisar seu código, vejo que é possivel fazer isso de forma simples, mesclando apenas 2 layouts: borderlayout e flowlayout, com 2 paineis. Já tentou mesclar assim?

Comment: Não dessa forma não fiz, no caso, ele separa os botoes e a tabela?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui isso no seu código modificando conforme abaixo:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class PosicionaTabela extends JFrame {

    private JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane();

    private JTable tabela = new JTable();

    private JButton botao1 = new JButton("1");
    private JButton botao2 = new JButton("2");
    private JButton botao3 = new JButton("3");

    public PosicionaTabela() {

        getContentPane().add(getButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(getTabelaPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(700, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private JPanel getTabelaPanel() {
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        jsp.setViewportView(tabela);
        jsp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        painel.add(jsp);
        return painel;
    }

    private JPanel getButtonsPanel(){       
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        painel.add(botao1);
        painel.add(botao2);
        painel.add(botao3);
        return painel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new PosicionaTabela().setVisible(true));
    }
}
```

Há alguns problemas no código, como você criar um `JPanel` e retorná-lo mas não adicionar nada nele. Criei um painel pra retornar o `JScrollPane` apenas pra exemplificar mas ele nem é necessário, tendo em vista que esta classe já é um container por si só e pode ser adicionada diretamente ao `JFrame`.

Mais informações a respeito de Layout Managers podem ser encontradas no [Guia oficial da oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Answer (score 2):

Fiz assim, usando um `BorderLayout` para ajudar:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class PosicionaTabela extends JFrame {

    public PosicionaTabela() {
        Tabela tab = new Tabela();
        add(tab);
        setSize(700, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new PosicionaTabela().setVisible(true));
    }
}

class Tabela extends JPanel {

    private JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane();

    private JTable tabela = new JTable();

    private JButton botao1 = new JButton("1");
    private JButton botao2 = new JButton("2");
    private JButton botao3 = new JButton("3");

    public Tabela() {
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        jsp.setViewportView(tabela);
        jsp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(painel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        painel.add(botao1);
        painel.add(botao2);
        painel.add(botao3);
    }
}
```

Eis o resultado:

[image: resultado]

Acerca do `EventQueue.invokeLater(...)`, veja mais sobre isso [nessa outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/132).