# Código trava a janela

Tags: java, gui

Tenho esse código no meu jogo e verifico se passou 400 milisegundos, e depois atualiza.

```
public void setUpdatePosition(int posicao, long tempo, int posX, int posY) {

    long previous = System.nanoTime();
    Point ponto = new Point(tiles[posicao].x, tiles[posicao].y);
    tiles[posicao].setPosition(posX, posY);

    while(((System.nanoTime() - previous) / 1000000) < tempo) {
        previous = System.nanoTime();
    }
    tiles[posicao].setPosition(ponto.x, ponto.y);
}
```

Mas acaba travando o meu jogo, como resolvo?

Comment: Você está fazendo tudo em uma única thread? Você poderia poupar o processador usando `Sleep` do Java, sem falar que liberaria para que outra thread fizesse seu trabalho sem concorrência de recursos

Comment: Você está usando o Swing? Se estiver, por favor, [leia esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/132).

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi dessa maneira, porém não sei se está correto.

```
public void setUpdatePosition(int posicao, long tempo, int posX, int posY) {

        Point ponto = new Point(tiles[posicao].x, tiles[posicao].y);
        tiles[posicao].setPosition(posX, posY);

        thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(tempo);
                    tiles[posicao].setPosition(ponto.x, ponto.y);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }

        });

        thread.start();
    }
```

Comment: Nwo, não está certo, ainda mais se for em swing. Leia o link passado nós comentários pelo @VictorStafusa.

Comment: Estou em dúvida quanto a isso. Já estou usando uma thread na minha classe JPanel(), que controla o gameLoop(), onde é renderizado e controlado a movimentação dos personagens e inimigos.

Comment: Já leu o link dos comentários?