# Como fazer consulta em um banco a partir de uma thread?

Tags: java, swing, thread

Um professor pediu pra desenvolver um projeto (um CRUD de carros). Já fiz a parte de inserir, remover, listar e alterar.

Porém a parte de listar deve ser feita por uma thread (exigência do professor), em que ela deve listar um carro a cada 20 segundos e mostrar em um `JTextArea`. A minha dúvida é de como fazer a thread fazer isso.

Segue o código:

Classe da `Thread` para listar. Obs: não fiz nada nessa classe ainda:

```
public class ThreadListar implements Runnable{


    private int tempo;


    public ThreadListar(int tempo) {
        this.tempo=tempo;

        Thread t1=new Thread(this);
        t1.start();

    }



    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(tempo);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Classe `CarroDAO` com o método de listar:

```
@Override
public ArrayList<Carro> listar() {

    ArrayList<Carro> carros= new ArrayList<Carro>();
    String sql="select * from carro";

try(Connection con= new ConnectionFactory().getConnection()){

    PreparedStatement ps= con.prepareStatement(sql);

    ResultSet rs= null;

    rs=ps.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next()) {

        Carro c= new Carro();

        c.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
        c.setMarca(rs.getString("marca"));
        c.setModelo(rs.getString("modelo"));
        c.setCor(rs.getString("cor"));
        c.setPlaca(rs.getString("placa"));

        carros.add(c);
    }   

    ps.close();
    rs.close();

}catch(SQLException e){

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao realziar consulta:"+e, "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    throw new RuntimeException(e);

}
    return carros;
}
```

Classe `Tela` (swing) com o botão e a ação de listar e setar os dados dentro do `JTextArea`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Tela frame = new Tela();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}

public Tela() {


JButton btnListar = new JButton("Listar");
    btnListar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {



            CarroDAO dao1 = new CarroDAO();

            ArrayList carros= dao1.listar();

            for(Object o: carros) {

                Carro c= (Carro) o;


                textArea.append(String.valueOf("ID: "+c.getId()+"\n"));
                textArea.append("Marca: "+c.getMarca()+"\n");
                textArea.append("Modelo: "+c.getModelo()+"\n");
                textArea.append("Cor: "+c.getCor()+"\n");
                textArea.append("Placa: "+c.getPlaca()+"\n"+"\n");
                textArea.append("=================");
            }

        }
    });


    btnListar.setBounds(234, 233, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnListar);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: E não está claro esse `e listar um carro a cada 20 segundos `, e quando a lista acabar, o que vai ocorrer? Esse listar vai ser feito após a pesquisa no banco? Precisa de mais detalhes sobre como deve funcionar isso.

Comment: Ah então foi por isso que você não respondeu direto ?,porque não falou antes?, era pra ter feito essas perguntas sobre as funcionalidades no início,pelo menos a gente não perderia tempo"discutindo". O que eu quero é: quando o usuário clicar no botão de listar a thread realize o método de listar(que é um select) da classe CarroDAO, e retorne(liste) todos os carros cadastrados no meu banco ,só que um a cada 20 segundos

Comment: Não precisa de thread para isso.  A não ser que Thread seja obrigatório, da pra fazer com um Timer. E por favor, vamos forcar apenas no problema da pergunta,

Comment: O meu professor exigiu que fizesse com threads, não é uma questão de "não precisa de thread", mas que é obrigatório o uso da thread nesse projeto

Answer (score 1):

Devido necessidade de se utilizar uma thread a parte  e a de temporização, pode-se utilizar a classe [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), que serve para agendar tarefas na JVM, e executá-las repetidamente (caso seja necessário) em um pool de threads paralela a atual. Não se pode esquecer que [**swing não é Thread-Safe**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/28595), portanto, devemos manter a alteração do componente na mesma thread responsável pela interface gráfica, a [**event-dispatch-thread**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/event-dispatch-thread/info).

No exemplo abaixo, eu crio apenas uma thread através do método `newScheduledThreadPool()` e programo a execução com o método `scheduleAtFixedRate()`, que recebe como parâmetros a tarefa que será executada, o delay inicial para ela começar, o intervalo de tempo entre cada execução e a unidade de tempo.

Por fim, dentro da tarefa, eu utilizei um contador para exibir os valores da lista a cada repetição da tarefa, e também para que se possa finalizá-la quando alcançar o fim da lista. A variável deverá ser um campo da classe, senão não será possivel modificá-la.

```
...

//o contador deverá ser uma variável de classe
private volatile int index = 0;

...

btnListar.addActionListener(e -> {

    CarroDAO dao1 = new CarroDAO();

    List<Carro> carros = dao1.listar();

    ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    Runnable run = () -> {

        if (index < carros.size()) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                textArea.append(String.valueOf("ID: " + carros.get(index).getId() + "\n"));
                textArea.append("Marca: " + carros.get(index).getMarca() + "\n");
                textArea.append("Modelo: " + carros.get(index).getModelo() + "\n");
                textArea.append("Cor: " + carros.get(index).getCor() + "\n");
                textArea.append("Placa: " + carros.get(index).getMarca() + "\n" + "\n");
                textArea.append("=================");
                index++;
            });
        } else {
            index = 0;
            ses.shutdown();
        }

    };
    ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(run, 0, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

});
```

Comment: O único detalhe é que você não está exatamente usando um pool de threads já que o pool criado só tem uma thread (`Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)`). Apesar disso, acho que a sua resposta deve ser **quase** correta e satisfatória: A listagem deveria acontecer dentro do `Runnable`!

Comment: Você poderia usar uma variável do tipo `AtomicInteger` ao invés de uma variável de instância `volatile`. Aliás, o comentário diz que ela é de classe, mas não é. Eu preferi usar um `Iterator` no lugar disso.

Comment: @VictorStafusa o fato da resposta está "completa" ou não é ponto de vista. Do meu, que tive um esforço em criá-la, pesquisar e testar antes, está mais que completa e funcional. Quanto a sugestões, eu foquei apenas no problema da pergunta e na explicação do autor nos comentários, dentro daquilo que eu tenho conhecimento.

Answer (score 1):

A [resposta do Articuno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252046/132) está no caminho certo. Entretanto, a separação do que vai na EDT daquilo que vai na thread fica mais fácil usando o [**`SwingWorker`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), inclusive tomando o cuidade de fazer a consulta ao DAO fora da EDT em uma thread auxiliar:

```
public class Tela extends JFrame {

    private final JButton btnListar;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Tela().setVisible(true));
    }

    public Tela() {
        this.btnListar = new JButton("Listar");
        btnListar.addActionListener(e -> realizarListagem());
        btnListar.setBounds(234, 233, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnListar);
    }

    private void realizarListagem() {
        btnListar.setEnabled(false);
        SwingWorker<Void, Carro> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Carro>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() {
                ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

                // Usamos o Iterator para acessar um carro por vez.
                Iterator<Carro> it = new CarroDAO().listar().iterator();

                Runnable run = () -> {
                    if (isCancelled() || !it.hasNext()) {
                        ses.shutdown();
                    } else {
                        // Pega o próximo carro e publica.
                        publish(it.next());
                    }
                };

                // Executa o Runnable uma vez a cada 20 segundos.
                ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(run, 0, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

                // Espera a lista de carros terminar.
                try {
                    ses.awaitTermination(99999, TimeUnit.DAYS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // Ignora a exceção e deixa o SwingWorker terminar graciosamente.
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<Carro> carros) {
                // Isto daqui NÃO deve ser uma lista com todos os carros.
                // Na verdade, espera-se que este método seja chamado com
                // um carro por vez.
                for (Carro c : carros) {
                    textArea.append(String.valueOf("ID: " + c.getId() + "\n"));
                    textArea.append("Marca: " + c.getMarca() + "\n");
                    textArea.append("Modelo: " + c.getModelo() + "\n");
                    textArea.append("Cor: " + c.getCor() + "\n");
                    textArea.append("Placa: " + c.getMarca() + "\n\n");
                    textArea.append("=================");
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                btnListar.setEnabled(true);
            }
        };
        worker.execute();
    }
}
```

O seu DAO também tem um problema: Se você já está usando o *try-with-resources*, então não deveria haver sentido chamar-se o método `close()` explicitamente. Eis como fica seu código revisado:

```
private static final String INSERT_SQL = "SELECT * FROM Carro";

@Override
public List<Carro> listar() {

    List<Carro> carros = new ArrayList<>();

    try (
        Connection con = new ConnectionFactory().getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    ) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            Carro c = new Carro();
            c.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            c.setMarca(rs.getString("marca"));
            c.setModelo(rs.getString("modelo"));
            c.setCor(rs.getString("cor"));
            c.setPlaca(rs.getString("placa"));
            carros.add(c);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao realziar consulta: " + e, "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return carros;
}
```

E observe que mudei o retorno de `ArrayList<Carro>` para `List<Carro>`. Há um princípio de programação que diz "*codifique para uma interface, e não para uma implementação*". Pois bem, `List` é uma interface e `ArrayList` é uma implementação.