# Como exibir o conteúdo de um arquivo .txt na tela?

Tags: java, swing, arquivo

Estou utilizando `JFrame` para tentar exibir os conteúdos de arquivos txt em uma janela e depois apagar todo o arquivo. Porém, quando coloco pra exibir, ele apaga o arquivo mais não exibe na tela que criei com `JFrame`. O que pode estar ocorrendo?

Segue o código:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Sistema;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author marqu
 */
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        lab = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        lab.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 255));
        lab.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        lab.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lab.setText("Controle da Catraca");

        jButton1.setText("Exibir historico");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(lab, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 372, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(142, 142, 142)
                        .addComponent(jButton1)))
                .addContainerGap(18, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(38, 38, 38)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(lab, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 210, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        String dir = "C:/Users/marqu/OneDrive/Documentos/marco.txt"; //String com o diretorio do arquivo txt
        Path caminho = Paths.get(dir); //Informa o caminho do arquivo txt
        byte[] txt = null;

        try {
            while (true) {

                do {
                    txt = Files.readAllBytes(caminho);// Ler o arquivo txt
                } while (txt.length <= 0); //Enquanto o arquivo txt estiver vazio, fique preso nesse WHILE

                //System.out.println(); // METODO TEMPORARIO SO PARA VISUALIZAR
                lab.setText(new String(txt));
                Files.write(caminho, "".getBytes()); // Apaga tudo do arquivo txt
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }



    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lab;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Esse código não é executável. Adiciona o código completo do seu jframe para que possamos testar o problema.

Comment: ja adicionei irmao

Answer (score 1):

Esse laço infinito é a causa do travamento da aplicação, alias, não precisa desses dois laços para fazer o que você pretende. Aplicações swing executam numa thread única, chamada [event-dispatch-thread](/questions/tagged/event-dispatch-thread), e qualquer atividade mais longa deve ser feita em outra thread, chamda [swingworker](/questions/tagged/swingworker). Fazer laço infinito no action do botão, vai manter a aplicação travada.

Altere o método do botão conforme abaixo:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    // diretorio do arquivo txt
    String dir = "C:/Users/marqu/OneDrive/Documentos/marco.txt";
    Path caminho = Paths.get(dir);
    List<String> txt;

    try {
        txt = Files.readAllLines(caminho);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (String s : txt)
            builder.append(s);

        lab.setText(builder.toString());

        Files.write(caminho, "".getBytes());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }
}
```

O que mudei foi trocar o tipo da variavel `txt` para uma lista de string, que é o retorno do método `Files.readAllLines()`. Com esse array carregado, criei um  `StringBuilder` para poder carregar as linhas do arquivo numa string e finalmente adicionar no seu componente. Esse último passo não seria necessário, mas caso o arquivo possua múltiplas linhas, é interessante fazê-lo caso precise manipular as linhas separadamente.

Porém, `JLabel` não foi feito para exibir textos multi-linha. A não ser que o conteúdo do seu arquivo seja uma unica linha, isso não será problema, mas se for múltiplas linhas, sugiro que utilize uma [`JTextArea`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html). Se quiser aprender mais a respeito desse componente, veja [**este tutorial oficial**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) ensinando a utilizá-lo.

Se o objetivo for atualizar o componente automaticamente com um intervalo definido após o evento de clique do botão, veja uma solução [**nesta resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252046/28595).

Comment: o laço e o seguinte, tem um programa quevai ficar sempre adicionando linhas de textos em um arquivo .txt, e esse programa vai pegar essas  linhas de texto exibir numa janela e apagar o arquivo .txt, ai sempre vai ficar verificando o arquivo pegando oque tem neste arquivo exibindo e apagando

Comment: @MarcoAntonio Veja a atualização na resposta sugerindo leitura de uma psosivel solução do outro problema.