# Chat entre dois computadores diferentes

Tags: java, socket, redes, tcp

Sou nova nessa coisa de Socket e estou tendo problemas em conectar dois computadores que estão numa mesma rede. Quando executo o cliente e o servidor na mesma máquina, ele funciona... mas quando faço isso em máquinas diferentes, o servidor não identifica a conexão do cliente.

Já li muitas perguntas e respostas em diversos fóruns, assisti vídeos no youtube, tentei soluções diferentes, já coloquei o IP do servidor no código do cliente e nada...

Alguém saberia me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado? Obrigada!

Servidor

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Server extends JFrame implements ActionListener,Runnable  {
ServerSocket ss;
Socket s;
BufferedReader br;
BufferedWriter bw;
List list;
JButton btnExit;
JTextArea text;
JButton btnSend;

public Server() {
    setTitle("Secret Chat - Server");
    setSize(741,495);
    setLocation(300,0);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    list = new List();
    list.setBounds(10, 48, 692, 275);
    getContentPane().add(list);

    btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
    btnExit.setBounds(613, 11, 89, 23);
    getContentPane().add(btnExit);
    btnExit.addActionListener(this);

    text = new JTextArea();
    text.setForeground(UIManager.getColor("ToggleButton.focus"));
    text.setLineWrap(true);
    text.setBounds(10, 338, 692, 74);
    getContentPane().add(text);

    btnSend = new JButton("Send");
    btnSend.setBounds(613, 423, 89, 23);
    getContentPane().add(btnSend);
    btnSend.addActionListener(this);

    setVisible(true);

    try
    {           
        list.add("Aguardando conexão de cliente...\n");

        ss = new ServerSocket(8375);

        s = ss.accept();
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                s.getInputStream()));
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                s.getOutputStream()));
        bw.write("... Você está conectado! ...");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.flush();
        Thread th;
        th = new Thread(this);
        th.start();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //System.out.println("Exceção: " + e);
    }
}

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {

     new Server();         

  }

@Override
public void run() {
    try
    {
        s.setSoTimeout(1);
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exceção: " + e);
    }
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            list.add(br.readLine());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //System.out.println("Exceção: " + ex);
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     if (e.getSource().equals(btnExit))
         System.exit(0);
     else{try{
         list.add("Eu (Servidor): " + text.getText());
         bw.write("Patty " + text.getText());
         bw.newLine();
         bw.flush();
         text.setText("");
         } catch(Exception m){}
     }


}
```

}

Cliente

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

    public class Client extends JFrame implements ActionListener,Runnable 
{
    List list;
    JTextArea text;
    JButton btnExit;
    JButton btnSend;
    Socket s;
    BufferedReader br;
    BufferedWriter bw;

    public Client() {
        setTitle("Secret Chat - Client");
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        list = new List();
        list.setBounds(10, 47, 692, 275);
        getContentPane().add(list);

        text = new JTextArea();
        text.setLineWrap(true);
        text.setBounds(10, 338, 692, 74);
        getContentPane().add(text);

        btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
        btnExit.setBounds(613, 11, 89, 23);
        btnExit.addActionListener(this);
        getContentPane().add(btnExit);

        btnSend = new JButton("Send");
        btnSend.setBounds(613, 423, 89, 23);
        btnSend.addActionListener(this);
        getContentPane().add(btnSend);

        setSize(741,495);
        setLocation(300,0);

        setVisible(true);

        try{
            /*Put the current IP address for current machine  
            if you didn't have an actual server and clients
            if you have an actual server and clients put the client IP address*/
            s = new Socket("10.1.XX.XXX",8375); // é aqui onde coloco o IP do servidor
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
            bw.write("... Um usuário anônimo se conectou! ...");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
            Thread th;
            th = new Thread(this);
            th.start();

        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        new Client();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try
        {
            s.setSoTimeout(2500);
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            //System.out.println("Exceção: " + e);
        }

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                list.add(br.readLine());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //System.out.println("Exceção: " + e);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         if (e.getSource().equals(btnExit))
             System.exit(0);
         else {
             try
             {
                 list.add("Eu (Cliente): " + text.getText());
                 bw.write("Anônimo: " + text.getText());
                 bw.newLine();
                 bw.flush();
                 text.setText("");
             } catch(Exception ex)
             {
                 //System.out.println("Exceção: " + ex);
             }
         }

    }                    
}
```

Comment: Testei localhost e funcionou perfeitamente. Infelizmente não tem como eu testar em maquinas diferentes, mas provavelmente você precisa passar o ip do servidor no cliente, e ver se não tem bloqueios de firewall tambem.

Comment: Outra coisa que quero alertar:[**sempre despache a aplicação grafica para a Event Dispatch Thread**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2017/28595)

Comment: O local funciona mesmo.. =/ o problema é quando tento com computadores diferentes (que é o que preciso).. O endereço que devo colocar é o Ipv4 que consigo através do comando ipconfig no cmd, certo? 

Muito obrigada pelo alerta! Farei isso. ^ w ^

Comment: Isso depende, se estiver em rede local, é o endereço fornecido pelo seu roteador. Você precisa verificar tambem o firewall. O windows costuma bloquear conexões de entrada.

Comment: Tudo bem! Vou verificar o firewall.

Comment: Experimente descomentar os Catchs tambem, eles existem justamente para apontar problemas na aplicação, se você deixar vazios, nunca vai saber a origem de problemas que causam exceções. Descomentei aqui seus catchs e apareceram varias mensagens de erro.

Comment: Sim.. descomentei aqui =/ Então.. já verifiquei o firewall (inclusive adicionei uma nova regra), mas... continua não funcionando

Comment: Para não mostrar mais aquelas exceções, eu mudei o setSoTimeOut para um valor bem alto...

Comment: É o firewall que está bloqueando mesmo, mas não consegui fazer o chat pegar sem desabilitá-lo, mesmo adicionando uma regra de entrada para a porta que está sendo utilizada no programa.