# Txt exibe informações duplicadas

Tags: java, mvc, txt

O que essa aplicação faz: o usuário tem que escolher qual a resposta certa para a pergunta. só coloquei por enquanto uma pergunta. Depois de **salvar a resposta** *(esta dentro de um .txt)* ele pode **ver resultado**.

E aí está o problema: ao clicar em ver resultado, ele mostra tudo direitinho *(na primeira vez,ele mostra null, ainda não consegui consertar isso)*. então eu fecho a janela dos resultados com o botão **fechar resultado** *(que aparece e desaparece com o setVisible)* , só que se eu clicar em **ver resultado** de novo, ele **duplica os valores na tela** , mas **somente** na tela, no txt está salvo tudo direitinho. queria que o usuário pudesse clicar quantas vezes ele quisesse no **botao ver resultado** e só aparecesse os erros e acertos das perguntas, sem duplicar os valores na tela.

[image: tela inicial. sempre que o usuário for jogar, ele pode ver seu desempenho, por exemplo: da primeira vez que eu joguei eu fiz X acerto e Y erros, da segunda ...]

se eu clico em ver resultado 3 vezes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como está salvo no txt (tudo certo)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
package visao;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class TelaPainel extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JButton btVerResultado;
private JButton btFecharResultado;
private JButton btSalvarRespostas;
private ButtonGroup grupo;
private JRadioButton radioDois;
private JRadioButton radioUm;

public TelaPainel() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    btVerResultado = new JButton("ver resultado");
    btVerResultado.setBounds(236, 156, 121, 23);
    contentPane.add(btVerResultado);

    btFecharResultado = new JButton("fechar resultado");
    btFecharResultado.setBounds(236, 156, 121, 23);
    btFecharResultado.setVisible(false);
    contentPane.add(btFecharResultado);

    btSalvarRespostas = new JButton("Salvar respostas");
    btSalvarRespostas.setBounds(22, 156, 131, 23);
    contentPane.add(btSalvarRespostas);

    JLabel lblQueAnimal = new JLabel("Que animal \u00E9 esse?");
    lblQueAnimal.setBounds(22, 45, 113, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblQueAnimal);

    radioUm = new JRadioButton("Cachorro");
    radioUm.setBounds(26, 75, 109, 23);
    contentPane.add(radioUm);

    radioDois = new JRadioButton("Gato");
    radioDois.setBounds(26, 113, 109, 23);
    contentPane.add(radioDois);

    grupo = new ButtonGroup();
    grupo.add(radioUm);
    grupo.add(radioDois);
    setVisible(true);
}

public JButton getBtVerResultado() {
    return btVerResultado;
}

public void setBtVerResultado(JButton brVerResultado) {
    this.btVerResultado = brVerResultado;
}

public JButton getBtFecharResultado() {
    return btFecharResultado;
}

public void setBtFecharResultado(JButton btFecharResultado) {
    this.btFecharResultado = btFecharResultado;
}

public JButton getBtSalvarRespostas() {
    return btSalvarRespostas;
}

public JRadioButton getRadioDois() {
    return radioDois;
}

public void setRadioDois(JRadioButton radioDois) {
    this.radioDois = radioDois;
}

public JRadioButton getRadioUm() {
    return radioUm;
}

public void setRadioUm(JRadioButton radioUm) {
    this.radioUm = radioUm;
}

public void setBtSalvarRespostas(JButton btSalvarRespostas) {
    this.btSalvarRespostas = btSalvarRespostas;
}
}

package visao;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class TelaExibir extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextArea textArea;

public TelaExibir() {
    setFocusable(true);
    setUndecorated(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 285, 164);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setLayout(null);
    textArea.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 100);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    scroll.setBounds(0, 0, 285, 164);
    contentPane.add(scroll);

    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
}

public JTextArea getTextArea() {
    return textArea;
}

public void setTextArea(JTextArea textArea) {
    this.textArea = textArea;
}
}

package modelo;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AlunoArquivo {

public static File arquivo = new File("exibir.txt");
static DadoResultadoAluno dra = new DadoResultadoAluno();
private static String c1;
private static String c2;

public static List<String> Read(String Caminho) {
    List<String> conteudo = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        FileReader arq = new FileReader(arquivo);
        BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(arq);
        String linha = "";
        try {
            linha = lerArq.readLine();
            while (linha != null) {
                conteudo.add(linha);
                linha = lerArq.readLine();
            }
            arq.close();
            return conteudo;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Erro: Não foi possível ler o arquivo!");
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Erro: Arquivo não encontrado!");
    }
    return null;
}


public static boolean Write(String Caminho,String Texto){
    try {
        if (!arquivo.exists()) {
            arquivo.createNewFile();
            System.out.println("not");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Yes");
            FileWriter arq = new FileWriter(arquivo, true);
            PrintWriter gravarArq = new PrintWriter(arq);
            gravarArq.println(Texto);
            gravarArq.close();
        }
        return true;
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}


public static void salvar(int countQtdAcertoPlanificacao, int countQtdErroPlanificacao, String ArqConfig){

    dra.setQtdAcertoPlanificacao(countQtdAcertoPlanificacao);
    dra.setQtdErroPlanificacao(countQtdErroPlanificacao);

    String print = dra.getQtdAcertoPlanificacao() + ";" + dra.getQtdErroPlanificacao();
    System.out.println("ultimo cont: "+countQtdErroPlanificacao + "");

    if (AlunoArquivo.Write(ArqConfig, print)) {
        System.out.println("Arquivo salvo com sucesso!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Erro ao salvar o arquivo!");
    }
}

public static void mostrar(String ArqConfig){
    List<String> conteudo = AlunoArquivo.Read(ArqConfig);

    for(String linha : conteudo) {
        c1 = linha.split(";")[0];
        c2 = linha.split(";")[1];
    }
}

public static String getC1() {
    return c1;
}

public static String getC2() {
    return c2;
}
}


package modelo;

public class DadoResultadoAluno {

private int qtdAcertoPlanificacao = 0;
private int qtdErroPlanificacao = 0;

public int getQtdAcertoPlanificacao() {
    return qtdAcertoPlanificacao;
}

public void setQtdAcertoPlanificacao(int qtdAcertoPlanificacao) {
    this.qtdAcertoPlanificacao = qtdAcertoPlanificacao;
}

public int getQtdErroPlanificacao() {
    return qtdErroPlanificacao;
}

public void setQtdErroPlanificacao(int qtdErroPlanificacao) {
    this.qtdErroPlanificacao = qtdErroPlanificacao;
}
}


package controle;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import modelo.AlunoArquivo;
import modelo.DadoResultadoAluno;
import visao.TelaExibir;
import visao.TelaPainel;

public class ControleTelaPainel implements ActionListener{

private static Integer countQtdErroPlanificacao = 0;
private static Integer countQtdAcertoPlanificacao = 0;
private String ArqConfig = "exibir.txt";
private DadoResultadoAluno dra;
private AlunoArquivo aa = new AlunoArquivo();
TelaExibir exibir = new TelaExibir();
private TelaPainel tp;

public ControleTelaPainel(TelaPainel tp) {
    this.tp = tp;
    this.tp.getBtFecharResultado().addActionListener(this);
    this.tp.getBtVerResultado().addActionListener(this);
    this.tp.getBtSalvarRespostas().addActionListener(this);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if(e.getSource()== tp.getBtFecharResultado()){

        this.tp.getBtVerResultado().setVisible(true);
        this.tp.getBtFecharResultado().setVisible(false);

        exibir.setVisible(false);
    }

    else if(e.getSource() == tp.getBtSalvarRespostas()){

        if(tp.getRadioUm().isSelected()){
            countQtdAcertoPlanificacao++;
        }else if(tp.getRadioDois().isSelected()){
            countQtdErroPlanificacao++;
        }
        AlunoArquivo.salvar(countQtdAcertoPlanificacao, countQtdErroPlanificacao, ArqConfig);
    }

    else if(e.getSource()== tp.getBtVerResultado()){

        AlunoArquivo.mostrar(ArqConfig);

        exibir.getTextArea().append("Você fez " + AlunoArquivo.getC1() + " acertos" + " e " + AlunoArquivo.getC2() + " tentativas erradas");
        exibir.getTextArea().append("\n\n");

        exibir.setVisible(true);
        this.tp.getBtFecharResultado().setVisible(true);
        this.tp.getBtVerResultado().setVisible(false);
    }
}
}

package controle;

import visao.TelaPainel;
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ControleTelaPainel ctp = new ControleTelaPainel(new TelaPainel());
}
}
```

Comment: Cadê os imports das classes??

Comment: formate as classes tambem, clicando em `{}`

Comment: coloquei os imports!

Comment: Gabriella, você não arrumou erros que lhe sugerir na outra resposta, sugiro que volte nela e leia atentamente, pois você continua mantendo codigos errados que eu já corrigi na resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/263720/28595

Comment: E eu lembro, mas agora é diferente. quando tento fazer dessa forma, as mensagens se duplicam

Comment: O erro null que você menciona eu já corrigi no outro código, releia a resposta e verá que eu comento sobre ele.

Comment: ok, mas na outra resposta, ao clicar duas vezes no botão exibir, ele duplica os valores igual está acontecendo nesse código. lá também não foi corrigido

Comment: Porque o problema lá era outro.

Comment: mas o null, eu só mencionei para que não pensassem que o fofo principal era esse. o foco principal é o fato de duplicar as mensagens na exibição. o null eu tento resolver depois

Comment: Sem resolver o null, o código nao é executavel.

Comment: da primeira vez de fato não ém mas quando roda a segunda vez, já é

Comment: Aqui não está rodando de forma alguma. Sugiro você editar porque deve ter faltado algo.

Comment: vou da uma olhada aqui, mas esses prints eu tirei dele em funcionamento. vou excluir o txt e ver do zero

Comment: aqui da erro, se eu tentar ver resposta primeiro, depois que eu salvo duas vezes, ou seja, respondo duas vezes , roda de boa

Comment: Então seu código tem mais erros que o da pergunta, que impedem de simular corretamente o problema.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70950/discussion-between-articuno-and-gabriella).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

O motivo de "duplicar" as linhas é porque você está utilizando o método `append()` no `JTexArea`, e este método vai concatenando novas strings em já existentes. Troque pelo método `setText()` que a concatenação não mais ocorrerá.

---

O código apresentado, apesar de já ser um exemplo executável, possui outros erros que não poderiam passar despercebidos e que está ligados, mesmo que de forma indireta, ao problema da pergunta, então vale a pena salientá-los e mostrar como corrigi-los.

Eis as duas unicas classes que alterei:

Na classe `ControleTelaPainel`:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ControleTelaPainel implements ActionListener {

    private DadoResultadoAluno dra = new DadoResultadoAluno();
    TelaExibir exibir = new TelaExibir();
    private TelaPainel tp;

    public ControleTelaPainel(TelaPainel tp) {
        this.tp = tp;
        this.tp.getBtFecharResultado().addActionListener(this);
        this.tp.getBtVerResultado().addActionListener(this);
        this.tp.getBtSalvarRespostas().addActionListener(this);
        lerResultados(0);

    }

    public void lerResultados(int indice) {
        List<String> linhas =  AlunoArquivo.Read();

        if(linhas == null)
            return;

        dra.setQtdAcertoPlanificacao(Integer.parseInt(linhas.get(indice).split(";")[0]));
        dra.setQtdErroPlanificacao((Integer.parseInt(linhas.get(indice).split(";")[1])));
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == tp.getBtFecharResultado()) {

            this.tp.getBtVerResultado().setVisible(true);
            this.tp.getBtFecharResultado().setVisible(false);

            exibir.setVisible(false);
        }

        else if (e.getSource() == tp.getBtSalvarRespostas()) {

            if (tp.getRadioUm().isSelected()) {
                dra.setQtdAcertoPlanificacao(dra.getQtdAcertoPlanificacao() + 1);
            } else if (tp.getRadioDois().isSelected()) {
                dra.setQtdErroPlanificacao(dra.getQtdErroPlanificacao() + 1);
            }
            AlunoArquivo.salvar(dra);
        }

        else if (e.getSource() == tp.getBtVerResultado()) {

            exibir.getTextArea().setText("Você fez " + dra.getQtdAcertoPlanificacao() + " acertos" + " e "
                    + dra.getQtdErroPlanificacao() + " tentativas erradas");

            exibir.setVisible(true);
            this.tp.getBtFecharResultado().setVisible(true);
            this.tp.getBtVerResultado().setVisible(false);

        }
    }
}
```

Fiz as seguintes mudanças:

- as variáveis `countQtdErroPlanificacao` e `countQtdAcertoPlanificacao` não são necessárias, tendo em vista que sua classe `DadoResultadoAluno` já tem a finalizade de armazenar os erros e acertos das perguntas;
- criei o método `lerResultados()` para que você possa utilizá-lo para ler os resultados do arquivo de texto e carrega-los na classe `DadoResultadoAluno`. No exemplo, eu só estou lendo a primeira linha, mas se você for implementar multiplos usuários respondendo o questionário, bastará fazer um loop com esse método para recuperar todas as linhas;
- tendo em vista que a classe `AlunoArquivo` é que precisa fazer persistência no arquivo de texto, a variável `ArqConfig` nesse contexto é desnecessária e até viola o principio de responsabilidade da classe;
- dentro do if `(e.getSource() == tp.getBtSalvarRespostas()`, alterei para:

  ```
  else if (e.getSource() == tp.getBtSalvarRespostas()) {

      if (tp.getRadioUm().isSelected()) {
          dra.setQtdAcertoPlanificacao(dra.getQtdAcertoPlanificacao() + 1);
      } else if (tp.getRadioDois().isSelected()) {
          dra.setQtdErroPlanificacao(dra.getQtdErroPlanificacao() + 1);
      }
      AlunoArquivo.salvar(dra);
  }
  ```

uma vez que você usava contadores para guardar respostas certas e erradas, quando essa é a responsabilidade da classe `DadoResultadoAluno`. Ao invés de contadores e incrementos, basta recuperar o valor dos getters e somar com um, passando este resultado para os setters.

- no if `(e.getSource() == tp.getBtVerResultado())` alterei para:

  ```
  else if (e.getSource() == tp.getBtVerResultado()) {

      exibir.getTextArea().setText("Você fez " + dra.getQtdAcertoPlanificacao() + " acertos" + " e "
              + dra.getQtdErroPlanificacao() + " tentativas erradas");

      exibir.setVisible(true);
      this.tp.getBtFecharResultado().setVisible(true);
      this.tp.getBtVerResultado().setVisible(false);

  }
  ```

uma vez que, como já citado anteriormente, a classe `DadoResultadoAluno` é que armazena os resultados, iremos apenas recuperar dela esses valores. Aqui também é a origem do erro inicial da pergunta, alterando para `setText()` o problema não ocorre mais. O método `AlunoArquivo.mostrar(ArqConfig);` não é mais necessário nem existir com essas alterações acima, como já irei explicar mais abaixo.

---

Na classe `AlunoArquivo`:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AlunoArquivo {

    public static File arquivo = new File("exibir.txt");

    public static List<String> Read(String Caminho) {
        List<String> conteudo = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            FileReader arq = new FileReader(arquivo);
            BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(arq);
            String linha = "";
            try {
                while (linha != null) {
                    conteudo.add(linha);
                    linha = lerArq.readLine();
                }
                arq.close();
                return conteudo;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Erro: Não foi possível ler o arquivo!");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Erro: Arquivo não encontrado!");
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static boolean Write(String Texto) {
        try {
            if (!arquivoExiste()) {
                arquivo.createNewFile();
                System.out.println("not");
            } 

            System.out.println("Yes");
            FileWriter arq = new FileWriter(arquivo, true);
            PrintWriter gravarArq = new PrintWriter(arq);
            gravarArq.println(Texto);
            gravarArq.close();

            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void salvar(DadoResultadoAluno dra) {

        String print = dra.getQtdAcertoPlanificacao() + ";" + dra.getQtdErroPlanificacao();

        if (AlunoArquivo.Write(print)) {
            System.out.println("Arquivo salvo com sucesso!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Erro ao salvar o arquivo!");
        }
    }

    public static boolean arquivoExiste() {
        return arquivo.exists();
    }
}
```

Ficou bem mais enxuta, e as alterações que fiz foram:

- criei um método para você checar se o arquivo existe, assim você fica livre de ter que ficar capturando exceções para checar isso;
- nos métodos `Read()` e `Write()`, eu adicionei a verificação citada acima, o que elimina capturar o `FileNotFoundException`;
- no método `Write()`, ao verificar se um arquivo existe, você cria ele mas não salva o resultado. Isso faz o arquivo ser criado vazio, e o resultado salvo pela primeira vez ser perdido. Apenas removendo o `else` este problema é resolvido;
- no método `salvar()`eu removi as redundancias que tinha com aqueles dois contadores que removemos na outra classe, e agora basta passar uma instancia de `DadoResultadoAluno` já que é ela que salva os resultados;
- como pode ter percebido, a responsabilidade de persistir é apenas da classe `AlunoArquivo`, não tem necessidade de outras classes nem conhecer o caminho para o arquivo, por isso algumas assinaturas nessa classe o caminho foi removido como parametro;
- com as mudanças que fizemos na classe anterior, o método `mostrar()`, `getC1()` e `getC2()` se tornaram obsoletos e desnecessários, pois você já tem o método `Read()` para ler as linhas do arquivo e quem lê os resultados é a classe explicada anteriormente.

---

Com essas "pequenas mudanças, seu código está mais organizado, além de termos separado responsabilidades para cada classe. Mas tem outras coisas que dá pra melhorar, mas não está ligado direta ou indiretamente ao problema.

Comment: Corretíssimo! obrigada