# Programa funciona debugando, mas não executando

Tags: java, swing

Estou fazendo um jogo da velha e gostaria de saber se o botão apertado que eu configurei na classe `MenuPrincipal` está retornando o valor correto pra classe main que controla a mudança entre as janelas.

Executando normalmente o programa não funciona, porém ao colocar um breakpoint na linha 16 da classe main, na linha `if(menu.botao)`, e colocar pra debugar no Eclipse o programa executa da forma correta.

Método main:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import interfaceMenu.MenuPrincipal;

public class main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

        MenuPrincipal menu = new MenuPrincipal();
        menu.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        menu.setSize(500, 500);
        menu.setVisible(true);
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,menu.getOpcao());
        while(true) {
            if(menu.botao) {
                System.out.println("botao apertado");

            switch (menu.getOpcao()) {
            case "Novo Jogo" : 
                                System.out.println("Botao Novo jogo apertado"); break;
            case "Sair": 
                System.out.println("Botao Sair apertado");break;
            default: System.out.println("nada");
            }

            menu.setOpcao("Nada selecionado");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Classe MenuPrincipal:

```
package interfaceMenu;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Menu;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class MenuPrincipal extends JFrame {

    private final JLabel textoInicial = new JLabel("Jogo da velha");
    JPanel areaDosBotoes = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
    private JButton[] botoes = new JButton[2];
    private String opcao = "Nada selecionado";
    public boolean botao = false;

    public MenuPrincipal() {

        super("Jogo da Velha"); // Barra de titulo;     
        botoes[0] = new JButton("Novo Jogo");
        botoes[1] = new JButton("Sair");    
        //TODO: MAIS OPÇÕES
        areaDosBotoes.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, botoes.length));
        for (JButton botao : botoes) {
            areaDosBotoes.add(botao);
            botao.addActionListener(new TratadorDeEventos());
        add(textoInicial, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(areaDosBotoes, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }
    }


    private class TratadorDeEventos implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            setOpcao(arg0.getActionCommand());
            botao = true;
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, getOpcao());
        }

    }

    public String getOpcao() {
        return this.opcao;
    }

    public void setOpcao(String opcao) {
        this.opcao = opcao;
    }
}
```

Comment: Você ta misturando interface grafica com modo de texto, talvez essa deve ser a razao.

Comment: O problema persiste mesmo usando JOptionPane.showMessageDialog em vez println ali na classe main

Comment: A partir do momento em que o botao é apertado, ele sera eternamente true, e seu loop jamais parara de executar.

Comment: Não sei qual o sentido de usar modo de texto em interface grafica, e qual a utilidade desse loop infinito que nunca para, mas voce precisa definir o momento em que o laço deve ser finalizado, senão nao vai sair do loop nunca.

Comment: Sim, eu esqueci de, após ter apertado botão, setar se o botao foi apertado pra false, porém mesmo assim ele deveria ao menos dar certo na primeira execução, certo? Vou corrigir isso do botão sempre true

Comment: Esse loop infitnito será finalizado quando for apertado o botão sair, entretanto preciso primeiro saber se a classe main está pegando a opção correta de botão apertado

Comment: Sua lógica está errada, swing por si já é uma API que roda sob um loop, você está adicionando outro e isso vai travar a aplicação, sugiro q retire esse loop, ele não é necessário para a interface funcionar, alias, ele vai é atrapalhar. Experimente remover todo o código do while e verá, a tela não precisa desse loop. Se quer controlar os botoes pressionados, está fazendo da maneira errada.

Comment: então, qual seria a maneira correta de controlar os botão apertados?

Comment: Dentro do actionlistener.

Comment: Por que desfez minha ediçao? Não tinha motivo para isso, eu apenas melhorei alguns trecho do texto, não alterei nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que se quer controlar a execução dos botões, essa forma que está fazendo não é adequada por dois motivos:

- Primeiro que as interfaces feitas com a API swing são [despachadas para uma nova thread](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/28595), e fazer operações fora deste laço para controlar a tela poderá ocorrer problemas de concorrência de threads, já que o método main executa em uma thread diferente.
- Segundo porque a API já possui todo um suporte para este tipo de situação, e o mais indicado é utilizar o proprio `ActionListener`, uma vez que ele também ocorre dentro da mesma thread da interface.

Para demonstrar que esse laço é irrelevante, você pode executar o código abaixo, com as alterações que fiz:

```
package swing.examples7;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class MenuPrincipal extends JFrame {

    private final JLabel textoInicial = new JLabel("Jogo da velha");
    JPanel areaDosBotoes = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
    private JButton[] botoes = new JButton[2];
    private String opcao = "Nada selecionado";
    public boolean botao = false;

    public MenuPrincipal() {

        super("Jogo da Velha"); // Barra de titulo;
        botoes[0] = new JButton("Novo Jogo");
        botoes[1] = new JButton("Sair");
        // TODO: MAIS OPÇÕES
        areaDosBotoes.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, botoes.length));
        for (JButton botao : botoes) {
            areaDosBotoes.add(botao);
            botao.addActionListener(new TratadorDeEventos());
            add(textoInicial, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(areaDosBotoes, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 500);
    }

    private class TratadorDeEventos implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, arg0.getActionCommand());               
            botao = true;

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new MenuPrincipal().setVisible(true));
    }

}
```

Em funcionamento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Além das alterações relativas ao `ActionListener` e a remoção do loop infinito, vale ressaltar outros pontos alterados no código, que é importante  levar em consideração:

- Como já mencionei, interfaces swing **devem ser sempre iniciadas** dentro da thread [event-dispatch-thread](/questions/tagged/event-dispatch-thread), no link já citado você encontrará melhores esclarecimentos dos motivos disso;
- Você está definindo características da tela fora dela sem nem ter definido na própria tela, isso é uma violação ao encapsulamento e também não faz muito sentido. O próprio objeto deve possuir todas as informações necessárias no momento que é criado, e essas características devem ser informadas no construtor da tela. Por estes motivos eu movi os métodos `setSize()` e `setDefaultCloseOperation()` para o construtor.