# Trabalho utilizando Thread

Tags: java, thread

Estou fazendo um trabalho da faculdade quem tem que ser utilizado *thread*. Mas nunca usei e estou aprendendo ainda. A minha intenção é, quando for pressionada a tecla up do teclado, *startar* a *thread* para fazer um evento. Mas está dando um erro que não estou conseguindo descobrir o porquê desse erro.

ERRO:

> ```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
> at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:708)
> at trabalho.Jogo.keyPressed(Jogo.java:52)
> at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6491)
> at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6310)
> at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2238)
> at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2025)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
> at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2296)
> at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
> at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
> at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:835)
> at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1103)
> at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:974)
> at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:800)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4760)
> at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2296)
> at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
> at org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper$6.dispatchEvent(AtkWrapper.java:715)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
> ```

---

```java
public class Jogo extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

    private CenarioInterno cenarioInterno;

    private Homer homer;
    private Cenario cenario;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Jogo jogo = new Jogo();

    }

    public Jogo() {

        this.addKeyListener(this);

        this.setSize(800, 700);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setResizable(true);

        cenarioInterno = new CenarioInterno(200000, 200000, "moesbar.jpg");
        cenario = new Cenario(0, 0, "cenario.jpg");
        homer = new Homer(80, 440, "homer.gif");

    }

    static ThreadImagemInterna r = new ThreadImagemInterna();
    static Thread thread = new Thread(r);

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            homer.movimentoFrente();
            repaint();
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            homer.movimentoTras();
            repaint();
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {

            thread.start();
            repaint();

        }

        System.out.println("Tecla Apertada: " + e.getKeyChar() + " Codigo da tecla: " + e.getKeyCode());

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    public void paint(Graphics graficos) {

        graficos.drawImage(cenario.getImage(), cenario.getX(), cenario.getY(), null);
        graficos.drawImage(homer.getImage(), homer.getX(), homer.getY(), null);
        graficos.drawImage(cenarioInterno.getImage(), cenarioInterno.getX(), cenarioInterno.getY(), null);

    }

}
```

---

```java
public class ThreadImagemInterna extends DesenhoMovel implements Runnable {

    CenarioInterno cenarioInterno = new CenarioInterno();

    @Override
    public void run() {



        }
    }
```

Comment: Por favor, forneça um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel testar o codigo e verificar o problema.

Comment: @DoutorStephenStrange https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5359/132

Comment: @VictorStafusa Obrigado pelo ensinamento!  show!!!

Answer (score 4):

Uma thread só pode ser iniciada uma vez. Tentar chamar o método `start()` em uma thread já iniciada te dá essa exceção que você tem: `java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException`.

A thread é criada, mas não iniciada, aqui:

```
    static ThreadImagemInterna r = new ThreadImagemInterna();
    static Thread thread = new Thread(r);
```

Quando a seta para cima é pressionada (`KeyEvent.VK_UP`), no seu método `keyPressed(KeyEvent)`, você faz isso:

```
            thread.start();
```

Se você pressionar a seta para cima de novo, o `start()` será chamado uma segunda vez para a mesma thread, o que não é permitido. O resultado é essa exceção.

O seu código não é o suficiente para saber o que você queria de fato fazer, mas algumas das ideias seriam:

- Criar a thread dentro do `keyPressed(KeyEvent)`.
- Colocar tarefas a serem executadas pela sua thread em um fila e fazer ela consumir as tarefas que estão nessa fila.
- Utilizar um [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).
- Definir alguma flag em algum lugar e fazer a sua thread observar essa flag.

Também recomendo você dar uma olhada [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2017/132).

Comment: Beleza, vou dar uma olhada. Valeu pela ajuda.