# IllegalArgumentException ao adicionar componentes ao JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Estou a fazer um projecto do jogo Sokoban, e cheguei á parte em que criei 2 JButtons para selecionar o nivel. Agora quando tento correr uma programa da um erro. Eu criei ambos os botoes e a açao numa class Buttons e chamei-a essa class noutra class que dá start ao programa. Usei o seguinte para os botoes:

```
public class Buttons extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Buttons(){
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JButton lvl1btn = new JButton("Level 1");
        JButton lvl2btn = new JButton("Level 2");
        lvl1btn.setBounds(700,0,100,25);
        lvl1btn.setBounds(800,0,100,25);
        lvl1btn.addActionListener(this);
        lvl2btn.addActionListener(this);
        lvl1btn.setActionCommand("Level 1");
        lvl2btn.setActionCommand("Level 2");
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String action = e.getActionCommand();
        if(action.equals("Level 1")){
            Board board = new Board();
            board.createWorldOne();
        }else if(action.equals("Level 2")){
            Board board = new Board();
            board.createWorldTwo();
        }
    }
```

E chamei assim:

```
public final class SokobanStart extends JFrame {

public SokobanStart() {
    InitUI();
}

public void InitUI() {
    Board board = new Board();
    Buttons buttons = new Buttons();
    add(board,buttons);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(board.getBoardWidth(),board.getBoardHeight());
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle("Sokoban Game!");
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SokobanStart sokobanStart = new SokobanStart();
    sokobanStart.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

E deume a seguinte thread:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add to layout: constraint must be a string (or null)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.BorderLayout.addLayoutComponent(BorderLayout.java:431)
>       at java.desktop/javax.swing.JRootPane$1.addLayoutComponent(JRootPane.java:507)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1148)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:1025)
>       at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(JFrame.java:553)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:993)
>       at Sokoban.SokobanStart.InitUI(SokobanStart.java:16)
>       at Sokoban.SokobanStart.(SokobanStart.java:10)
>       at Sokoban.SokobanStart.main(SokobanStart.java:25)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa linha aqui é causa do erro:

```
add(board,buttons);
```

Você não colocou um código completo, então estou supondo que essa classe `Board` seja algum outro componente que você tenha criado.

Se olhar na documentação da classe [`JFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html), verá que nenhum dos métodos `add` que ela herda recebe 2 componentes ao mesmo tempo, essa linha está errada. Se quer adicionar board e buttons no `JFrame`, precisa ser um de cada vez, você precisa quebrar essa adiçao:

```
add(board);
add(buttons);
```

Só que isso apenas ainda daria erro porque a classe `Buttons` é um JFrame  e você não pode adicionar um JFrame dentro de outro. Você terá que transformar essas classes `Buttons` e `Board` em [`JPanel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) se quiser adicionar elas dessa forma.

---

Vale ressaltar a recomendação abaixo:

> **Evite usar layout absoluto, a não ser que seja de extrema necessidade e que saiba as consequências disso**, pois layout absoluto dificulta manutenção da tela e faz com que sua aplicação fique com aparência diferente dependendo do monitor e resolução que estiver sendo executada.
>
> Existem vários [**gerenciadores de layouts**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) para que você não tenha que se preocupar com posicionamento ou organização manual de componentes. Sem contar que o uso de layouts faz com que seu código fique mais fácil de dar manutenção do que ficar inserindo um monte de `setbounds`, e caso precise alterar a posição de algum componente, no layout absoluto, vai ter que reposicionar todos manualmente.

E também vale a pena alertar que todas as aplicações gráficas envolvendo a API swing devem ser [**despachadas para a EDT**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2017/28595).

Recomendo para estudo: [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)

Comment: Boas. Agradeço a ajuda o erro ja nao existe. Porem,agora a janela aparece em branco. Estive a fazer alguma pesquisa e nao consigo encontrar o motivo.

Comment: @Phil Se essa resposta resolveu o erro, é interessante fechar essa questao, clicando no `v` ao lado. Se há uma nova duvida, é recomendado que abra uma nova pergunta contendo um codigo completo que seja **[mcve]**, assim fica mais facil te ajudar.

Comment: Eu ainda estava a editar o comentario mas os 5 minutos passaram. Continuando ,ia dizer que tenho varias classes que definem os varios objectos e estes sao chamados na classe Board exceto a classe buttons pois nao consigo fazer com que ele execute essa classe chamando-a no board. Portanto chamo ambos no Start e adiciono-os ao JPanel. No entanto se eu eliminar os botoes ja aparece o jogo conforme planeado.Com os botoes aparece a janela em branco.

Comment: @Phil como eu ja disse, voce está questionando um problema completamente diferente da pergunta que fez, como eu disse, é mais interessante pra organizacao do site voce encerrar essa questao como resolvido clicando no `v` e fazendo uma nova pergunta, contendo um **[mcve]** senao fica complicado ajudar sem poder executar.

Comment: @Phil sem um [mcve] realmente nao tem como eu te dizer o motivo do problema. Mas desconfio, apenas lendo o que vc comentou, que a causa é o gerenciador de layouts. Se fornecer um exemplo minimo e executável do codigo com o problema mencionado, eu posso sugerir alguma alteracao que resolva iso.

Comment: coloquei uma nova pergunta relacionado com esse problema