# Como pegar o valor de uma JSpinner, dentro de um loop?

Tags: java, swing

Estou montando uma tela onde são exibidos produtos de um banco de dados: titulo do produto, preço, botao e um spinner. Tento dar um getValue do jspinner, porém ele não me retorna o valor que o usuário indica.

```
public class Minimo extends JFrame {

    JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
    JButton botao = new JButton("adicionar");

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));

    public Minimo() throws HeadlessException {
        super("Produtos em Estoque");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            spinner = new JSpinner();
            botao = new JButton();
            botao.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    System.out.println(spinner.getValue());

                }
            });

            panel.add(botao);
            panel.add(spinner);

        }

        add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(1360, 720);


    }




     public static void main(String[] args) {
                new Minimo();
            }
}
```

Quando clico no respectivo botao do jspinner, não é exibido no console o valor contido no jspinner.

[image: print da tela]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este código não irá funcionar como você espera pois a cada iteração do laço, você cria um spinner e um botão relacionado, mas na iteração seguinte, perde qualquer referencia aos que foram criados na iteração anterior.

O fato de usar variáveis com escopo muito amplo dentro do laço só piora a situação, pois só ficará armazenado o botao e spinner da última iteração. Por esta razão, todos os botões refletem apenas o que está marcado no último spinner.

A solução mais simples seria armazenar os spinners e botoes em arrays, e utilizar o indice deles pra conseguir identificar no listener. Lembrando que, como tem o mesmo numero de botoes e spinners, eu utilizei o indice do botao para identificar o spinner relacionado:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Minimo extends JFrame {

    JSpinner[] spinners = new JSpinner[10];
    JButton[] botoes = new JButton[10];

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));

    public Minimo()  {
        super("Produtos em Estoque");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
            JButton botao = new JButton();
            botao.setActionCommand(String.valueOf(i));

            botao.addActionListener(e -> {

                    JButton btn =  (JButton) e.getSource();
                    int index = Integer.valueOf(btn.getActionCommand());
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Valor do spinner " + (index+1) + ": " + spinners[index].getValue());
            });

            spinners[i] = spinner;
            botoes[i] = botao;

            panel.add(botao);
            panel.add(spinner);

        }

        add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(1360, 720);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Minimo::new);
    }
}
```

No código acima, também utilizei [**`setActionCommand()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Button.html#setActionCommand-java.lang.String-) nos botões, pois você precisa passar uma refência fixa do indice para o listener, senão ocorrerá o mesmo problema de pegar sempre o ultimo. Com esse comando, eu registro o indice em cada botão, assim, quando passar pro listener, ele vai pegar o indice correto do spinner do qual aquele botao é relativo.

Outro erro no seu código é não definir o comportamento da janela quando for fechada. Por padrão, a janela é apenas ocultada, ficando em execução em segundo plano, você precisa alterar esse comportamento senão o usuário da sua aplicação não conseguirá abrir a janela uma segunda vez, a não ser que reinicie o computador. Por isso adicionei a linha `setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` no codigo, ela faz com que a janela seja realmente fechada, encerrando a aplicação corretamente.

Pra finalizar, você não está despachando sua aplicação para a [event-dispatch-thread](/questions/tagged/event-dispatch-thread) recomendo que leia [Por que o método main deve despachar a criação da GUI para a EDT em uma aplicação swing?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2017/28595) e corrija seu código.

Veja em funcionamento o código corrigido:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta Articuno, e também pela dica.

Comment: @teophilo fiz algumas alterações, recomendo que dê uma lida novamente quando puder.