# Como posicionar um browser dentro de outra interface JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, layout

Estou elaborando um projeto em Java para simular um servidor proxy com autenticação que apresenta uma única interface, no qual dentro dela fiquem dispostos vários quadros internos. Como posicionar um browser dentro desta interface `JFrame`?

Vejam o modelo do projeto:

[image: Modelo do projeto]

E o código:

```
\\Código do Browser
package view;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.*;

public class SwingHTMLBrowser extends JFrame implements ActionListener, HyperlinkListener {
    public JTextField addressBar;
    public JEditorPane pane;

    SwingHTMLBrowser() {

    super("Swing HTML Browser");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        addressBar = new JTextField();
        addressBar.addActionListener(this);
        pane = new JEditorPane();
        pane.setEditable(false);
        pane.addHyperlinkListener(this);
        add(addressBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(new JScrollPane(pane));
        setSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        String url = addressBar.getText();
        try {
            pane.setPage(url);
        } catch (IOException t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getEventType() != HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
            return;
        }
        JEditorPane srcPane = (JEditorPane)evt.getSource();
        if (evt instanceof HTMLFrameHyperlinkEvent) {
            HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument)pane.getDocument();
            doc.processHTMLFrameHyperlinkEvent((HTMLFrameHyperlinkEvent)evt);
        } else {
            String url = evt.getURL().toString();
            addressBar.setText(url);
            try {
                pane.setPage(url);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
       }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingHTMLBrowser browser = new SwingHTMLBrowser();
        browser.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow Vagner. E qual está sendo o resultado com esse código que você tem hoje?

Comment: O que voce pretende fazer? É como está na figura? O codigo não representa o que está na figura.

Comment: O código representa o browser. Se testado ele abre uma tela Jframe. É esta tela que pretendo que fique dentro da interface acima.

Comment: Só criar um JPanel com toda essa interface de browser e jogar num jframe,

Comment: Este é o problema, não consigo carregar essa interface dentro do Jframe, quando executo ela abre fora. Se testar você poderá perceber. Alías meu conhecimento em java é recente, por isso esse grau de dificuldade.

Comment: Não entendi sua duvida ainda. Você quer criar uma interface semelhante a figura correto? Se for isso é simples.

Comment: Isso mesmo, este é o objetivo. É um projeto de Programação Orientada a Objeto.

Comment: Se puderem me ajudar, posso colocar o nome da "stackoverflow" como principal intermediador do projeto e ficarei muito agradecido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui fazer assim:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkEvent;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLFrameHyperlinkEvent;

public class SwingHTMLBrowser extends JFrame {

    private JTextArea userStatus, serverStatus;
    private JPanel actions;


    SwingHTMLBrowser() {



        super("Swing HTML Browser");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));

        userStatus =  new JTextArea(5,5);
        JScrollPane userStatusPane = new JScrollPane(userStatus);
        userStatusPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("user Status"));
        userStatusPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.getPreferredSize().width/6, this.getPreferredSize().height));

        serverStatus = new JTextArea(5,5);
        JScrollPane serverStatusPane = new JScrollPane(serverStatus);
        serverStatusPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("server Status"));
        serverStatusPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.getPreferredSize().width/6, this.getPreferredSize().height));

        actions = new JPanel();
        actions.add(new JLabel("actions"));
        actions.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.getPreferredSize().width, 100));
        actions.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));

        add(actions, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel secondaryPane = new JPanel();
        secondaryPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(secondaryPane, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        secondaryPane.add(userStatusPane);
        secondaryPane.add(serverStatusPane);
        secondaryPane.add(new Browser());

        add(secondaryPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new SwingHTMLBrowser().setVisible(true));
    }
}

class Browser extends JPanel {

    private JTextField addressBar;
    private JEditorPane pane;

    public Browser() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        addressBar = new JTextField();
        pane = new JEditorPane();
        pane.setEditable(false);

        addressBar.addActionListener(e -> {
            String url = addressBar.getText();
            try {
                pane.setPage(url);
            } catch (IOException t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }

        });

        pane.addHyperlinkListener(evt -> {

            if (evt.getEventType() != HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
                return;
            }

            JEditorPane srcPane = (JEditorPane) evt.getSource();

            if (evt instanceof HTMLFrameHyperlinkEvent) {
                HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) pane.getDocument();
                doc.processHTMLFrameHyperlinkEvent((HTMLFrameHyperlinkEvent) evt);
            } else {
                String url = evt.getURL().toString();
                addressBar.setText(url);
                try {
                    pane.setPage(url);
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        add(addressBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(new JScrollPane(pane));
    }
}
```

Basicamente o que fiz foi tirar vantagem do gerenciador de layout padrão do `JFrame`([`Borderlayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)) e utilizar um painel secundário para poder distribuir verticalmente os 3 componentes, também tirando vantagem do layout padrão do `JPanel`([`FlowLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html)) que organiza os componentes de forma vertical, como foi exibido na figura.

Outra modificação é criar uma classe `Browser`, tendo em vista que se trata de uma implementação independente.

Outro ponto importante a salientar é que todas as aplicações gráficas envolvendo a API swing devem ser [**despachadas para a EDT**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2017/28595).

O resultado sai:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você é o cara. Obrigadão vou testar aqui.

Comment: Funcionou, Deus lhe abençoe.

Comment: @VagnerSantos se a resposta lhe ajudou, voce pode marca-la como aceita, clicando no  `v` ao lado dela.