# Exception in thread "main" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is decorated

Tags: java, swing, javafx, gui, awt

Galera voltei, comecei a estudar AWT fiz um programinha simples que apenas abria uma janela com um fundo verde, mas eu tento criar um evento pra janela do programa fechar e fica dando o erro do título

Erro:

> Exception in thread "main" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException:
>   Theframe is decorated     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.setOpacity(Frame.java:963)    at
>   Ventana.main(Ventana.java:19)

codigo que estou usando:

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;

public class Ventana {

    public static void exitForm(WindowEvent evt){
        System.exit(0);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Frame frame = new Frame("Novo video!");
        frame.setUndecorated(false);
        frame.setSize(600,600);
        frame.setLocation(520,250);
        frame.setOpacity((float)0.50);
        frame.setBackground(new Color(161, 203, 70));
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt){
                exitForm(evt);

           }


       });
        frame.show();



   }

}
```

sou bem novato, desculpa se estou fazendo um erro bem "noob", mas já agradeço pela atenção <3

Answer (score 1):

Vamos ver a [descrição do `setUndecorated`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated(boolean)):

> Disables or enables decorations for this frame.
>
> This method can only be called while the frame is not displayable. To make this frame decorated, it must be opaque and have the default shape, otherwise the `IllegalComponentStateException` will be thrown. Refer to [`Window.setShape(java.awt.Shape)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html#setShape(java.awt.Shape)), [`Window.setOpacity(float)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html#setOpacity(float)) and [`Window.setBackground(java.awt.Color)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html#setBackground(java.awt.Color)) for details

Traduzindo:

> Desativa ou ativa decorações para este frame.
>
> Este método só pode ser chamado quando o frame não é exibível. Para fazer este frame decorado, ele deve ser opaco e ter o formato padrão, caso contrário, o `IllegalComponentStateException` será lançado. Refira-se a [`Window.setShape(java.awt.Shape)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html#setShape(java.awt.Shape)), [`Window.setOpacity(float)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html#setOpacity(float)) e [`Window.setBackground(java.awt.Color)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html#setBackground(java.awt.Color)) para detalhes

Pois bem, o `frame.setUndecorated(false);` significa que o frame será decorado. Se ele for decorado, então, de acordo com a documentação deverá ser opaco. Entretanto, isso contradiz o especificado no `frame.setOpacity((float)0.50);`. Logo, você está colocando uma situação que a documentação do `setUndecorated` deixa claro que resulta em um `IllegalComponentStateException`.

Quando você usa o `frame.setUndecorated(false);`, significa que o frame trata-se de uma janela normal, de formato retangular, com ícones e bordas normais e sem transparência. O motivo disso é que esse é o tipo de janela padrão utilizado por 99% das janelas das nossas aplicações e que portanto é muito mais simples e mais rápido de ser tratado pelo sistema operacional.

Dificilmente você iria querer ou precisar de uma janela transparente ou não-retangular, e o seu código não indica que este seria o caso. Logo, sugiro apenas remover o `frame.setOpacity((float)0.50);`.

Ah, recomendo também dar uma [olhada nesta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2017/132), pois usar o swing dentro do `main` não é boa ideia. A melhor solução seria colocar o código que usa o swing em um método `private static void mostraTela() { /* ... */ }` e então no método `main`, usar um `EventQueue.invokeLater(Ventana::mostrarTela);`.

Além disso, o uso de `System.exit(0);` costuma ser uma má prática de programação. Evite isso e prefira usar um `frame.dispose();` dentro do seu método `windowClosing`.

Você também pode utilizar `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` para centralizar o frame.

Seu código completo, embora ainda não faça nada lá muito útil, ficaria assim:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;

public class Ventana {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(Ventana::mostrarTela);
    }

    private static void mostraTela() {
        Frame frame = new Frame("Novo video!");
        frame.setUndecorated(false);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setBackground(new Color(161, 203, 70));
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt){
                frame.dispose();
            }
        });
        frame.show();
   }
}
```

Comment: porque não é uma "boa ideia" usar o swing dentro do main?

Comment: Alías, tem como me dar um exemplo de como devo fazer? comecei a estudar Java a pouco tempo, e da maneira que estou aprendendo nunca usei isso;-;...teria como me dar um exemplo do "private static ..." enfim...um exemplo da maneira certa de se fazer

Comment: @joaoazevedo Coloquei o exemplo. Siga o [link que coloquei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2017/132) para ver o porquê de não ser boa ideia usar o swing dentro do `main`.